# How can I create custom controls in Android?

Tags: android, controls

I would like to create a custom control in my Android App. It will be a circular control with some smaller moveable circles that will indicate a specific value.

Is there a way to realize this?

Are there at least some nice tutorials where I can read how to create a custom control?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have a look at the [custom components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) section of the Android Dev Guide. The usual approach is to extend a [`View`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) and override applicable methods.

Comment: The [custom components tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) section is good, but it is unfortunately lacking when it comes to dealing with XML. I just finished posting [an answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml/2695649) to this part of it.