# Anyway to use XML layout files for specific View/ViewGroups?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, view

I have a custom `View` that I'd like to specify the layout of in an XML file rather than through code.

Is there anyway I can take an Android XML layout file and use it to flush out my custom `View`'s content?

I know it can be done in an `Activity` via the `setContentView` method, but there doesn't seem to be a similiar method for `Views`.

Comment: I think that this is a duplicate of  [Declaring a custom android UI element using XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the basic overview: In code for your activity, use `findViewById` to get the container of the subview you want to define in XML in the activity's main view.  Then, use `mySubview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.mysubview, mycontainerInRootView)` to build the new contained view.  Finally, you can use the returned subviews `findViewById` to hook the subview's controls into the main activity.

In a custom View class, you similarly need to just get a LayoutInflater instance do do the work for you, but the details will probably work out a little differently.  I'd make the custom View a ViewGroup subclass to start, then use LayoutInflater.from(ctx) in the constructor to get the inflater and go from there.  It would look something like `mContents = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.mycustomview, this)`.