# How to inflate XML-Layout-File correctly inside Custom ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to inflate a XML-Layout-File in a custom ViewGroup Class, my Problem is that it produces just a empty screen. Doing the same in the Activity Class works fine. 
Here is my simple XML-Layout-File:

```
shownumberlayout.xml:

    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" 
        android:id="@+id/layoutForNumber">

        <TextView 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:id="@+id/tvNumber"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
            android:textColor="#000000" 
            android:text="Test" 
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" 
            android:textSize="30dip">
        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the working Version, inflating the `shownumberlayout.xml` in the Activity `ShowNumber`:

```
ShowNumber.class

public class ShowNumber extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.shownumberlayout, null);
        setContentView(vg);
    }
}
```

This shows a White Background with the black Text “Test” centered.

Now the Version inflating the xml in the Custom `ViewGroup`-Class:

```
ViewGroup.class
public class ViewNumber extends ViewGroup {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public ViewNumber(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        initView(context);
    }

    public ViewNumber(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        initView(context);
    }

    public ViewNumber(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        initView(context);
    }

    private void initView(Context context){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.shownumberlayout, null);  
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

ShowNumber.class
public class ShowNumber extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ViewGroup vg = new ViewNumber(this); 
    setContentView(vg);
}
```

}

Im doing it basically like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3368182/anyway-to-use-xml-layout-files-for-specific-view-viewgroups) Answer explained.
This just produces a Empty Black Screen. What I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1**

**@Konstantin**
I applied your changes but still just a blank screen, i also made a log-ouput for getting the number of children. It remains always 1, even i add one more Textview to the XML-Layout-File. Before the Changes it remains always 0.

```
public class ViewNumber extends RelativeLayout {
...
private void initView(Context context){
        //inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //inflater.inflate(R.layout.shownumberlayout, null);
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.shownumberlayout,this); 
        Log.v("ViewNumber", "Number of Child: " + this.getChildCount());//output is 1,before it remains 0
    }
...
}
```

**@Sankar** This is the Logcat, after the Changes from Konstantin:

```
12-16 09:24:23.606: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8951): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
12-16 09:24:23.606: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8951): CheckJNI is OFF
12-16 09:24:23.606: DEBUG/dalvikvm(8951): creating instr width table
12-16 09:24:23.656: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8951): --- registering native functions ---
12-16 09:24:23.916: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8951): Shutting down VM
12-16 09:24:23.916: DEBUG/dalvikvm(8951): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
12-16 09:24:23.916: INFO/AndroidRuntime(8951): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
12-16 09:24:24.076: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8960): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
12-16 09:24:24.076: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8960): CheckJNI is OFF
12-16 09:24:24.076: DEBUG/dalvikvm(8960): creating instr width table
12-16 09:24:24.126: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8960): --- registering native functions ---
12-16 09:24:24.376: INFO/ActivityManager(78): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=org.customview.harold/.ShowNumber }
12-16 09:24:24.426: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(8960): Shutting down VM
12-16 09:24:24.426: DEBUG/jdwp(8960): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select
12-16 09:24:24.426: DEBUG/dalvikvm(8960): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
12-16 09:24:24.456: INFO/AndroidRuntime(8960): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
12-16 09:24:24.456: VERBOSE/ViewNumber(8923): Number of Child: 1
12-16 09:24:24.496: VERBOSE/RenderScript_jni(164): surfaceDestroyed
12-16 09:24:24.526: INFO/ActivityManager(78): Displayed activity org.customview.harold/.ShowNumber: 104 ms (total 104 ms)
12-16 09:24:24.576: DEBUG/dalvikvm(158): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 10631 objects / 526248 bytes in 52ms
12-16 09:24:34.606: DEBUG/dalvikvm(164): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1776 objects / 106960 bytes in 91ms
```

**UPDATE 2**

The Content is finally showing correctly up.
The missing thing was to override the Method `onLayout` (thanks to **Franco**) in the RelativeLayout-Sublcass:

```
public class ViewNumber extends RelativeLayout {
...

    @Override
            protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                for(int i = 0 ; i < getChildCount() ; i++){
                    getChildAt(i).layout(l, t, r, b);
                }
            }
...
}
```

Note: Later you should also override the Method `onMeasurement()`, but currently the content is also showing correctly without overriding it.

Now the solution for the Method `initView` from **Franco** do not align the TextView in the Center, but puts it in the top left corner. The solution from **Konstantin** puts it correctly in the Center of the View:

```
public class ViewNumber extends RelativeLayout {
...
private void initView(Context context){
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.shownumberlayout,this); 
    }
...
}
```

Comment: @Harlod: Please See your Logcat and tell what Message you caught inj Your Logcat?

Comment: yes Harold, you're right, i tried it and see it in the hierarchy view tool and the TextView is aligned in the top left corner with width and height = 0

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
private void initView(Context context){
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.addView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.shownumberlayout, null));  
    }
```

EDIT: I respond quickly... a ViewGroup has the responsibility to prepare the layout for their children, in the layout method try this:

```
        @Override
        protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            for(int i = 0 ; i < getChildCount() ; i++){
                getChildAt(i).layout(l, t, r, b);
            }
        }
```

Comment: YES! Its working, the content is showing..Thank you very much! I will update my Post.

Comment: all right! be sure that you override both methods, onLayout and onMeasurement, always that you subclass the ViewGroup class.

Comment: This particular answer gave me a problem when instantiating several views from the same XML. I fixed this problem replacing the onLayout method in your answer with super(changed, l, t, r, b); Otherwise it's just great and I thank you for it!

Comment: Hey, I have an XML-File with a LinearLayout and 2 nested TextViews inflated as Franco shows in his post. The inflate works but in the onLayout-method I get a NullpointerException. To make it precise: getChildAt(i) gives me the LinearLayout but when I call getChildAt(i).layout(l, t, r, b) I get a NullPointerException. Can anyone give me a hint why?

Answer (score 48):

I don't know what's going on in these answers.. I think calling `onLayout` manually is a bit crazy.

The `LayoutInflater.inflate` function is rather straight forward. If you're using the one that accepts the 3rd boolean argument (attachToRoot) and it's **true**, it will add the views from your XML to your parent view (the 2nd argument). If you're using the one that accepts only 2 arguments, it will pass **true** to attachToRoot by default if you provide a parent that isn't **null**.

In any case, most of the mess you're experiencing is because the views from your XML are added to your custom view. Since your XML has a `RelativeLayout` root and your custom view is also a `RelativeLayout` - you're getting a relative layout inside a relative layout.

*This is probably not what you want.*

The answer given by Konstantin makes sense, but you're wasting a view because you're placing a `RelativeLayout` inside a `FrameLayout`. Since Android can't hold too many nested views, it's a good idea to optimize and not add this unnecessary `FrameLayout`.

I suggest keeping your custom view as `RelativeLayout` and changing your XML root to `<merge>`. Then use the inflate form which adds the XML views to your parent - like `View.inflate(context,int,this)`

The purpose of the `<merge>` tag is to skip the root node in the XML.. look it up.

Comment: it is indeed. For everyone who is still confused about layout inflating here is great article which pretty well explains how it should be done: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/

Comment: @Ran This is not a real answer. This is only a complaint. A real answer would have be brief, straightforward and would have shown a code snippet like the accepted one does, or like Konstantin's one. _Yet +1 to that complaint._

Answer (score 36):

Your layout is inflated nowhere.. make your ViewNumber extend FrameLayout and inflate into it:

```
public class ViewNumber extends FrameLayout {

    public ViewNumber(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView(context);
    }

    public ViewNumber(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context);
    }

    public ViewNumber(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView(context);
    }

    private void initView(Context context){
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.shownumberlayout, this);  //correct way to inflate..
    }
}
```

UPD: Also you do not need to override onLayout method, that looks very incorrect.. at least call super.onLayout() on the very start:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
}
```

Comment: I applied your changes, but still a blank screen. See my updated post.

Comment: @Harold: I think that's because your implementation of onLayout is completely incorrect, see update.

Comment: @Harold: oh I see that @Franco already pointed that out. But if you look carefully, my original snippet has no onLayout method in it, probably I should be more verbose next time :)

Comment: @KonstantinBurov Your choice of variable for the parameter is hard to understand at first. Could you change them to Left, top, right, bottom instead of l,t,r,b. :)

Comment: @codingbiz Thx, updated. Though I believe the original code was generated by IDE based on the method signature.

Answer (score 2):

Overriding `onLayout` is necessary.when you create a object of ViewNumber(`ViewGroup vg = new ViewNumber(this)`),it is like inflating xml below:

```
<ViewNumber
           I have no child :(
</ViewNumber>
```

so if you don't override `onLayout`,ViewNumber's `onLayout` can't find any child,then it will be blank.

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
}
```

after overriding,it will use the onLayout method of ViewNumber's parent, if your codes is:

```
public class ViewNumber extends RelativeLayout {
...
private void initView(Context context){
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.shownumberlayout,this); 
    }
...
}
```

then it's like inflating xml below

```
  <RelativeLayout
    <RelativeLayout 
            your xml file
                   />
  </RelativeLayout>
```

there is one more RelativeLayout.To sovle this,you may write:

```
public class ViewNumber extends RelativeLayout {
...
private void initView(Context context){
        inflater.inflate( R.layout.login_view_layout, null );
              //change (..,this) to (..,null)
    }
...
}
```

However, something unexpected will happen.`android:layout_xxx=".."`of your xml file may change(this is why your text is put in the top left corner). To learn more and a better solution,you can see **talkol**' answer and **fgeorgiew**'s comment under it :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
 inflater.inflate( R.layout.login_view_layout, null );
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 1):

I come across the same question and answer my version in **Kotlin**:

You can add your customise views by xml or code. The difference is the constructor.

**YourView.kt**

```
class YourView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : LinearLayout(context, attrs) {

    init {
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.your_view, this, true)
     orientation = HORIZONTAL
    }
}
```

If you want to create your layout from code then just use:

```
class YourView(context: Context) : LinearLayout(context)
```

**your_view.xml**

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/searchView"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel" />


</merge>
```

What's the `<merge>` here for?

If you use `YourView` in the layout like:

```
<LinearLayout> 
   <YourView>
   </YourView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then the actual view hierarchy is:

**with** `<merge>`

```
   <LinearLayout>
      <TextView> </TextView>
      <Button> </Button>
   </LinearLayout >
```

**without** `<merge>` (You need to use `ViewGroup` like `<LinearLayout>`)

```
 <LinearLayout> 
       < LinearLayout >
          <TextView> </TextView>
          <Button> </Button>
       </LinearLayout >
    </LinearLayout>
```