# Adding buttons programmatically to a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, button, fragment

I'm trying to programmatically add image buttons to the fragment that is a part of a viewpager. I tried different codes, but no button shows up even though Eclipse returns no error.

I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448779/how-to-inflate-xml-layout-file-correctly-inside-custom-viewgroup) but the answers didn't help me make my buttons appear.

Here is my code.

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

private ViewPagerActivity mViewPagerActivity;
private String mId;

public ViewPagerFragment(String id) {
    mId = id;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    if (activity instanceof ViewPagerActivity) {
        mViewPagerActivity = (ViewPagerActivity)activity;
    }
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

     int[] image_array = {
            R.drawable.elebutton,
            R.drawable.right,
            R.drawable.middle,
            };

     for (int i =0;i<image_array.length;i++){
            ImageButton b1 = new ImageButton(getActivity());
            b1.setId(100 + i);
             b1.setImageResource(image_array[i]);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if (i > 0) {
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, b1.getId() - 1);
            }   
            b1.setLayoutParams(lp);

            ImageHolder ih = new ImageHolder(getActivity());
            ih.addView(b1);


    }

    return v;

}
public class ImageHolder extends FrameLayout {

    public ImageHolder(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initView(context);
    }

    public ImageHolder(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initView(context);
    }

    public ImageHolder(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        initView(context);
    }

    private void initView(Context context){
        View.inflate(context, R.layout.fragment, this); 
    }

   @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for(int i = 0 ; i < getChildCount() ; i++){
            getChildAt(i).layout(l, t, r, b);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Seems like you're adding your buttons in the ih object, you're also creating a ImageHolder for each button and your not adding anything to your real layout view v. So maybe instead of adding the  b1 in ih, you should add it in v => v.addView(b1).
Let me know if this makes sense and helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are creating i number of images, adding each of them to a imageholder. However, I did not see any part you actually join imageholders to main layout. So basically, these are created but not added to anywhere. Let us assume your R.layout.fragment has only a FrameLayout with id frameLayout1. Below would be my suggestion:

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

private ViewPagerActivity mViewPagerActivity;
private String mId;

public ViewPagerFragment(String id) {
    mId = id;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    if (activity instanceof ViewPagerActivity) {
        mViewPagerActivity = (ViewPagerActivity)activity;
    }
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
// IMPORTANT PART! Here we will add images after fragment is inflated and instantiated
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Get the root layout of fragment, we called it frameLayout1
    FrameLayout fl = (FrameLayout)(this.getActivity.findViewById(R.id.frameLayout1));
    int[] image_array = {
            R.drawable.elebutton,
            R.drawable.right,
            R.drawable.middle,
            };

     for (int i =0;i<image_array.length;i++){
            ImageButton b1 = new ImageButton(getActivity());
            b1.setId(100 + i);
             b1.setImageResource(image_array[i]);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            if (i > 0) {
                lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, b1.getId() - 1);
            }   
            b1.setLayoutParams(lp);

            ImageHolder ih = new ImageHolder(getActivity());
            ih.addView(b1);
            fl.addView(ih);
    }
}
// End of important part
public class ImageHolder extends FrameLayout {...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can refer to my answer on [Adding button to fragments dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210994/adding-buttons-to-fragments-dynamically).

Basically on your onCreateView method, implement this. Also, you should not use `getActivity()` for your ImageButton but use `yourView.getContext()` instead.

```
View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

 for (int i = 0; i < image_array.length; i++) {

            final ImageButton b1 = new ImageButton(myView.getContext());
            b1.setImageResource(image_array[i]);
            b1.setId(i + 1);
            b1.setOnClickListener(this);

//Change the linearlayout to relative layout for your context
//you should set another layout within your R.layout.fragment
            LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.btnholder); 
            linearlayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams buttonParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            buttonParams.setMargins(left, top, right, btm);

            linearlayout.addView(b1, buttonParams);
}
```

Hope this helps. I had the same problem for a while when I was creating normal button. If you need anything else, let me know :).