# Create Custom Compound View in Android with Attributes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I have created a custom compound view inside a library application and everything was OK. When I add custom attributes to view, I always get default values. I followed [this steps](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) with only one difference: my view is in a library project.

/res/values/attrs.xml

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="DatePickerView">
        <attr name="showToday" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="calendar" format="enum">
            <enum name="jalali" value="0" />
            <enum name="gregorian" value="1" />
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Layout file that contains view:

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:farayan="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/net.farayan.android.view"
...
    <net.farayan.android.view.datepicker.DatePickerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        farayan:showToday="false"
        farayan:calendar="gregorian"/>
...
```

Component's code:

```
int calendar;
boolean showToday;

TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.DatePickerView, 0, 0);
try {
    calendar = a.getInteger(R.styleable.DatePickerView_calendar, 0);
    showToday = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.DatePickerView_showToday, true);
} finally {
    a.recycle();
}
```

`calendar` and `showToday` are always `0` and `true` respectively. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we add new compound view code and its attributesinside project, we should add this at the beginning of layout:

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your_main_app_package
```

and if new compound view is inside a library project linked to our peoject, we should add this:

```
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto
```

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10217752/1152549

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is not right here:

```
    <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:farayan="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/net.farayan.android.view"
```

What about change to:

```
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:farayan="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/net.farayan.android.view"
```

`net.farayan.android.view` is your app root namespace.

***update1***

xmlns:farayan="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/your_main_app_package"

[Here](https://github.com/etao-open-source/cube-sdk/blob/master/sample-and-tests/res/layout/fragment_dotview.xml) is am example. It use a view defined in the library project.

Comment: net.farayan.android.view is my root package declared in manifest file.

Comment: As I told before, my view is defined in library application that is attached to the main app. attr.xml is also defined in library app. If I change `lib` to `res` while defining xml namespace, I get this error: `No resource identifier found for attribute 'calendar' in package`

Comment: Is your code published anywhere? I appreciate your approach (just changing the layout of original calendar by changing YEAR, MONTH, DAY values to Jalali, so everything goes original beyond UI)

Comment: @AliBehzadianNejad, has your problem been solved? I was working on a library project and dealt the same issue. I updated the answer. Hope that would be helpful.

Comment: @Xaqron I am doing a new version and it is not finished yet. When it finishes, I will publish it in my GitHub (https://github.com/alibehzadian/)