# Custom View attributes are not accessible in xml android

Tags: android, view, xml-namespaces

I am trying to set **drawable in xml of my CustomView**. but it is not showing my `app:enableProgressRes="@drawable/vbequalizer_bg"`  or `customname:enableProgressRes="@drawable/vbequalizer_bg"`

I mean *custom attributes are not included*. As we hit `Ctrl+Space` android:attr  shows.

> And i have tried including these namespaces one by one to the Root Layout.

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:customname="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/zare.custom.views"
```

> But my attributes aren't accessible in xml. by anyOne of them

[This answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10217752/3496570) that the Problem is resolved after ADT 17.

**attrs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <declare-styleable name="VolumnBar">
        <attr name="disableProgressRes" format="integer" />
        <attr name="enableProgressRes" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

**CustomView(VolumeBar) Constructor**

```
public VolumnBar(Context context, AttributeSet attributeset)
{
    super(context, attributeset);

    if(!isInEditMode())
    {
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attributeset, R.styleable.VolumnBar);//VolumnBar same name as Class Name

        try
        {
            drawableProgress = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.VolumnBar_disableProgressRes);

            drawableInvalidateProgress = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.VolumnBar_enableProgressRes);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
        finally
        {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper format for drawable resources is `reference`, no `integer`. Change your attribute definitions to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="VolumnBar">
        <attr name="disableProgressRes" format="reference" />
        <attr name="enableProgressRes" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: yes the proper format of it is reference. but I have created some Custom View using integer and they are working fine. And after testing your code problem doesn't solve.