# Android - HorizontalListView not inflating in XML from Class file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have added [the library](https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android) to my project.

Then in XML file I am trying to add the `HorizontalListView` as the following

```
<com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalList"
        android:layout_width="284dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#ddd" />
```

But it gives the following `Exception`

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.golfer/com.golfer.WeatherScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #256: Error inflating class com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #256: Error inflating class com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.golfer-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.golfer-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I have followed the instructions on [this site](http://www.dev-smart.com/archives/34)

Any one having any idea about it? Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it the following way,

Add `devsmartlib.jar` to the `libs` folder.

Then go to `Java Build Path - > Libraries` and `Add JAR` `devsmartlib.jar` to the project.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView` by the name of your package +name of the class.

Something like this: `com.example.android.MyHorizontalView` where `com.example.android` is the **name of your package** and `MyHorizontalView` is the name of the class (that you created).

**EDIT**

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461407/help-with-a-custom-view-attributes-inside-a-android-library-project) and [android developer](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html), you are probably missing a line to declare the namespace of the view. Try adding a line like this one

```
 xmlns:widget="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.mypackage"
```

In the parent layout (below the line `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`)

Comment: I did not created the class. The class is in the library I am using. And it is the package name of the library. However I also tried to copy the `HorizontalListView` file from library to my own project and then I used it like `com.mypackage.HorizontalListView` even in that case same issue was there.

Comment: if you declare an object com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontialListView in your Activity, can you import the class or do you get a compilation error ?

Comment: That's the point man, I have already imported it like `import com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView;` and it works there. But not in XML file.

Comment: Should I try writing my package name there or library's package name ?

Comment: same Error am facing . I am using this HorizontialListView class in Remote View. Am using this class only. not library any solution

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the Lib to your Dependencies? If not, add it!

**Edit** 
Eclipse:
Right-Click on Project-> Build Path-> Configure Build Path-> Libraries-> Check if lib is in there, if not -> add Library.....

Comment: Can you please explain where you are saying ?

Comment: @AndroidUser what IDE are you using?

Comment: Eclipse IDE I am using.