# Custom Attributes in Android

Tags: android, custom-attributes

I'm trying to create a custom attribute called Tag for all editable elements. I added the following to attrs.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="Spinner">
    <attr name="tag" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>

<declare-styleable name="EditText">
    <attr name="tag" format="string" />
</declare-styleable>
```

I get an error saying "Attribute tag has already been defined" for the EditText. Is it not possible to create a custom attribute of the same name on different elements?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If you are going to use an attr in more than one place then put it in the root element inside the `<resources>` element like the following :

```
<resources>
    
    <attr name="tag" format="string" />

    <declare-styleable name="Spinner">
        <attr name="tag" />
    </declare-styleable>

    <declare-styleable name="EditText">
        <attr name="tag" />
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Now you can use the tag attribute in anywhere you want inside this xml file.

Answer (score 5):

See if my detailed answer about custom attributes helps: [Defining custom attrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/android-defining-custom-attrs/3441986#3441986)