# Using a non-android namespace prefix in child elements in a layout

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, namespaces

I am trying to use custom attributes in some Android layouts, but I am getting an error (from Eclipse) when I try to use a namespace prefix other than `android:` in a child element.  Note that it works ok when I use the `custom:` namespace prefix in the root/parent element in the file, just not the child element.

For example, here's a simple layout with the custom namespace specified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    custom:my_tag1="whatever">                            <!-- compiles fine -->

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        custom:my_tag2="true"/>                           <!-- generates an error -->
</LinearLayout>
```

The error that Eclipse gives (only on the *second* attempt to use the `custom:` prefix) is:

> Unexpected namespace prefix "custom" found for tag ImageView.

If I make my root element an `ImageView` instead of a `LinearLayout`, the prefix is accepted.  So it seems to be just a problem using the namespace prefix in a child element.

Also, if I try to add another `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` attribute to the ImageView, it complains as well.

If it helps, here is the `attrs.xml` file I'm using with the above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="my_tag1" format="string"/>
    <attr name="my_tag2" format="boolean"/>
</resources>
```

I've seen some stuff online that leads me to believe what I want to do should be possible.  For example, in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs), Qberticus uses the prefix "whatever" in a child class.  Similarly in the post [here](http://blog.pocketjourney.com/2008/05/02/android-tutorial-42-passing-custom-variables-via-xml-resource-files/).

I don't get it.  Is using a non-android namespace prefix just not allowed for child elements, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Xylian Unfortunately, not.  Sorry.  I ended up working around it by using custom attributes in `styles.xml` instead though.

Comment: See this it might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568632/custom-attributes-in-android

Comment: I think it is Eclipse code analizer issue. Maybe you could add exception for Eclipse somewhere in settings. You could try to build project directly from command line. I pretty sure you will have success. Also it's time to migrate to AndroidStudio vs Gradle. It is pleasure ti work with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be ignored, I always did it and I didn't encounter any problems.
To make it go away you need to set the following:

1. add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to your root view
2. add `tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"` to your text view

On a side note, however, I usually use custom attributes with custom views :-)