# Shadow color on buttons depending on state in XML - Android

Tags: android, xml, button

I've created custom ToggleButtons in Android and since all buttons inherit from the same xml I want to change how they act depending on state, so when the state is checked I want to change the shadow color but this does not seem to possible with the current SDK.

I've created an xml file which holds button_colors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:color="#FFFFFF"  />

<item
    android:color="#000000" />
 </selector>
```

But this only seems to work with text-color and not shadow color on the text.
Is there something I'm missing?
And rather not do this for every button manually in code since I want this to apply to every button in the app.

**UPDATE EDIT:**

My selector currently looks like this

```
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:state_checked="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_gradient_selected" />

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/button_gradient" />

</selector>
```

But as I mentioned to the commentator below I can't seem to change the style/text-color-shadow from here since it only can take in a drawable it seems.

When I try to put in a different style on the button in here it force closes or either does not change the style depending on state. When I only try to put in the style here and have the drawable be set in the style it force closes. Either way it does not work it seems.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add shadow to TextView on selection/focus](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753158/how-to-add-shadow-to-textview-on-selection-focus)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to my solution on a different StackOverFlow question. I extended `TextView` to give a working solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753158/how-to-add-shadow-to-textview-on-selection-focus/10530570#10530570). (Replace TextView with Button)

Answer (score 8):

Seems that the Android framework does not support this.

From TextView.java:

```
        case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextView_textColor:
            textColor = a.getColorStateList(attr);
            break;

        case com.android.internal.R.styleable.TextView_shadowColor:
            shadowcolor = a.getInt(attr, 0);
            break;
```

They treat textColor and shadowColor differently.

Comment: @jukuYou are right, this is not implemented in android framework as it should be

Comment: Let's star http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17689 and push to get it done.

Answer (score -1):

This is the Selector file you have to implement:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle_off" /> 
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_toggle_on" /> 
  </selector>
```

These are the picture tey used for the default ToggleButton:
[btn_toggle_on](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_on.9.png;h=53e95af9697d3ba1ca4802db4e25dbbdf877b5a1;hb=f1f07993792dbf2d49613d474a696ec0927828d2) and [btn_toogle_off](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/drawable-mdpi/btn_toggle_off.9.png;h=26ee1c2e9259f3caa06c41caefb6d72703439820;hb=f1f07993792dbf2d49613d474a696ec0927828d2)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not the answer since a drawable can not change shadow color only the background drawable.

According http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html you should use a separate selector for colors, but this does not seem to apply to shadow.

I already have an XML that selects drawable but can not figure out how to change the shadowcolor or style from there.

Comment: @Joakim Engstrom: I think that i am not getting you properly. Can you post the screenshot of your activity. Then it will be undestandable for me.

Answer (score -3):

**You can have a selector for the shadow color like this: color_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:dither="true">
    <item 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:color="@color/btn_text_on" />
    <item 
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:color="@color/btn_text_on" />
    <item
        android:color="@color/btn_text_off" />        
</selector>
```

**and then use this selector while styling your button in styles.xml like this:**

```
<style name="ButtonStyle">
<item name="android:textColor">#FF383C48</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@drawable/color_selector</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">1</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">1</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```