# Declaring styleable attributes in Android

Tags: android, xml, styleable, declare-styleable

There's precious little documentation about the `declare-styleable` tag by which we can declare custom styles for components. I did find [this list](http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=179) of valid values for the `format` attribute of the `attr` tag. While that's nice as far as it goes, it doesn't explain how to use some of those values. Browsing [attr.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml) (the Android source for the standard attributes), I discovered that you can do things like:

```
<!-- The most prominent text color.  -->
<attr name="textColorPrimary" format="reference|color" />
```

The `format` attribute can evidently be set to a combination of values. Presumably the `format` attribute helps the parser interpret an actual style value. Then I discovered this in attr.xml:

```
<!-- Default text typeface. -->
<attr name="typeface">
    <enum name="normal" value="0" />
    <enum name="sans" value="1" />
    <enum name="serif" value="2" />
    <enum name="monospace" value="3" />
</attr>

<!-- Default text typeface style. -->
<attr name="textStyle">
    <flag name="normal" value="0" />
    <flag name="bold" value="1" />
    <flag name="italic" value="2" />
</attr>
```

Both of these seem to declare a set of allowed values for the indicated style.

So I have two questions:

1. What's the difference between a style attribute that can take on one of a set of `enum` values and one that can take on a set of `flag` values?
2. Does anyone know of any better documentation for how `declare-styleable` works (other than reverse engineering the Android source code)?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There's this question here: [Defining custom attrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/android-defining-custom-attrs) with *some* info, but not much.

And this [post](http://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/android-custom-xml-attributes-and-views/) . It has good info about flags and enums:

> **Custom XML Attribute Flags**
>
> Flags are special attribute types in
>   that they are allowed only a very
>   small subset of values, namely those
>   that are defined underneath the
>   attribute tag.  Flags are specified by
>   a “name” attribute and a “value”
>   attribute.  The names are required to
>   be unique within that attribute type
>   but the values need not be.  This is
>   the reason that during the evolution
>   of the Android platform we had
>   “fill_parent” and “match_parent” both
>   mapping to the same behavior.  Their
>   values were identical.
>
> The name attribute maps to the name
>   used in the value place within the
>   layout XML and does not require a
>   namespace prefix.  Hence, for the
>   “tilingMode” above I chose “center” as
>   the attribute value.  I could have
>   just as easily chosen “stretched” or
>   “repeating” but nothing else.  Not
>   even substituting in the actual values
>   would have been allowed.
>
> The value attribute must be an
>   integer.  The choice of hexadecimal or
>   standard numeral representation is up
>   to you.  There’s a few places within
>   the Android code where both are used
>   and the Android compiler is happy to
>   accept either.
>
> **Custom XML Attribute Enums**
>
> Enums are used in an almost identical
>   manner as flags with one provision,
>   they may be used interchangeably with
>   integers.  Under the hood Enums and
>   Integers are mapped to the same data
>   type, namely, an Integer.  When
>   appearing in the attribute definition
>   with Integers, Enums serve to prevent
>   “magic numbers” which are always bad. 
>   This is why you can have an
>   “android:layout_width” with either a
>   dimension, integer, or named string
>   “fill_parent.”
>
> To put this into context, let’s
>   suppose that I create a custom
>   attribute called
>   “layout_scroll_height” which accepts
>   either an integer or a string
>   “scroll_to_top.”  To do so I’d add an
>   “integer” format attribute and follow
>   that with the enum:
>
> ```
> <attr name="layout_scroll_height" format="integer">  
>     <enum name="scroll_to_top" value="-1"/> 
> </attr>
> ```
>
> The one stipulation when using Enums
>   in this manner is that a developer
>   using your custom View could
>   purposefully place the value “-1″ into
>   the layout parameters.  This would
>   trigger the special case logic of
>   “scroll_to_top.”  Such unexpected (or
>   expected) behavior could quickly
>   relegate your library to the “legacy
>   code” pile if the Enum values were
>   chosen poorly.
>
> ---

As I see it, the real values you can add in reality to an attribute is limited by what you can obtain from it. Check the `AttributeSet` class reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/AttributeSet.html) for more hints.

You can obtain:

- booleans (`getAttributeBooleanValue`),
- floats (`getAttributeFloatValue`),
- ints (`getAttributeIntValue`),
- ints (as `getAttributeUnsignedIntValue`),
- and strings (`getAttributeValue`)

Comment: Thanks for those links. The Statically Typed blog is particularly nice. It's close enough to "real documentation" that I'm marking this as solved.

Comment: @Ted indeed, that post has great info. Anyhow, unless you're writing a library of reusable views, or extending the framework, I would not worry about these enums. Bools, floats, ints and strings can get you far for regular custom views. That is, of course, if the question was not just to satisfy a very healthy curiosity :)

Comment: @Aleadam - The question was motivated by a real application. I've been using custom attributes and needed to add a new one. It turns out that the right format for the new attribute is an enum, but until reading the link you provided, I couldn't find any info on the difference between using `enum` and `flag`.

Comment: @Ted I'm glad it was useful. There are a few other posts in that blog that seem interesting, although I just skim through it, I did not have the time to read them yet.

Comment: +1 for anyone who links my blog.  I really tried to parse through what each one of those tags was used for.  It may not be complete and perhaps should be updated as time goes on but if anyone has anything to add to it, I'm all ears.

Comment: Well, +10 to you for providing the info! Please, fell free to add/modify/remove anything @wheaties

Comment: Is there a way to make the enum value be ~0 for bitwise operations?

Answer (score 77):

@Aleadam 's answer is very helpful, but imho it omits one major difference between `enum` and `flag`. The former is intented for us to pick one, and only one value when we assign the corresponding attribute for some View. The latter's values can be combined, however, using the bitwise OR operator.

An example, in `res/values/attr.xml`

```
<!-- declare myenum attribute -->
<attr name="myenum">
    <enum name="zero" value="0" />
    <enum name="one" value="1" />
    <enum name="two" value="2" />
    <enum name="three" value="3" />
</attr>

<!-- declare myflags attribute -->
<attr name="myflags">
    <flag name="one" value="1" />
    <flag name="two" value="2" />
    <flag name="four" value="4" />
    <flag name="eight" value="8" />
</attr>

<!-- declare our custom widget to be styleable by these attributes -->
<declare-styleable name="com.example.MyWidget">
    <attr name="myenum" />
    <attr name="myflags" />
</declare-styleable>
```

In `res/layout/mylayout.xml` we can now do

```
<com.example.MyWidget
    myenum="two"
    myflags="one|two"
    ... />
```

So an enum selects one of its possible values, while flags can be combined. The numerical values should reflect this difference, typically you'll want the sequence to go `0,1,2,3,...` for enums (to be used as array indices, say) and flags to go `1,2,4,8,...` so they can be independently added or removed, using bitwise OR `|` to combine flags.

We could explicitly define "meta flags" with values that are not a power of 2, and thus introduce a kind of shorthand for common combinations. For instance, if we had included this in our `myflags` declaration

```
<flag name="three" value="3" />
```

then we could have written `myflags="three"` in stead of `myflags="one|two"`, for completely identical results as `3 == 1|2`.

Personally, I like to always include

```
<flag name="none" value="0" /> <!-- or "normal, "regular", and so on -->
<flag name="all" value="15" /> <!-- 15 == 1|2|4|8 -->
```

which will allow me to unset or set all flags at once.

More subtly, it might be the case that one flag is implied by another. So, in our example, suppose that the `eight` flag being set should force the `four` flag to be set (if it wasn't already). We could then re-define `eight` to pre-include, as it were, the `four` flag,

```
<flag name="eight" value="12" /> <!-- 12 == 8|4 -->
```

Finally, if you are declaring the attributes in a library project but want to apply them in layouts of another project (dependent on the lib), you'll need to use a namespace prefix which you must bind in the XML root element. E.g.,

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ... >

    <com.example.MyWidget
        auto:myenum="two"
        auto:myflags="one|two"
        ... />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Good points. I suppose that to someone familiar with enums from programming languages, the difference between a flag and an enum would be second nature. (I didn't even realize that the point you were making was missing from Aleadam's answer.) This is definitely useful additional information. +1

Comment: This answer clearly points to how to differenciate enums from flags while defining custom attributes. It clearly helped me using flags :) +1