# How to set multiple background colors in Android(Java) MP Charts Based On Y- axis Range

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

I want to set multiple background colors in a chart view. A single color can be set in a background of the chart view but there is no way to set multiple colors.

Percentage-wise wants to add background color 0% to 20% - Red color, 21% to 60% - White and 61% to 100% in green color[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qC0D.png)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using a layer-list for the background?
Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/green" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="400dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        <size android:height="100dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:top="600dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/red" />
        <size android:height="200dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

I think that if you want an actual percentage you'll need to calculate it yourself. see this answer -> [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6061494/4156497)

Comment: I tried with layer list.. but  color is  going out of the chart  and i want change the Bg color dynamically based on  percentage values.

Comment: I understand, try the approach in the link I mentioned, I think that's what you need.
Good luck :)