# Android drawable xml reverse corners

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable

I'm trying to replicate the following shape in Android studio:

[image]

I can't figure out how to do it in android drawable xml.

At the moment I used a layer-list where:
As the first item I placed a transparent (or white) rectangle, to which I gave a padding on the left side and vertically.
As the second item I placed a rectangle containing the gradient and the corners on the left.

Now, I don't know how I can make the two "reverse angles" on the right, I've tried everything but online there aren't many examples to refer.

Here's my current code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">

                    <solid android:color="@color/transparent" />
                    <padding
                        android:bottom="8dp"
                        android:left="8dp"
                        android:right="0dp"
                        android:top="8dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">

                    <gradient
                        android:angle="0"
                        android:endColor="@color/green"
                        android:startColor="@color/blue"
                        android:type="linear" />
                    <corners
                        android:bottomLeftRadius="22dp"
                        android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
                        android:topLeftRadius="22dp"
                        android:topRightRadius="0dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>

</layer-list>
```

How can I change the code to obtain this shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:width="600dp"
        android:height="400dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">

            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:endColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:startColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>


    <item android:width="600dp"
        android:height="100dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:bottomRightRadius="100dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:width="600dp"
        android:height="100dp"
        android:top="300dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <corners android:topRightRadius="100dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:width="200dp"
        android:height="200dp"
        android:top="100dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:width="600dp"
        android:height="200dp"
        android:top="100dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <gradient
                android:angle="0"
                android:endColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:startColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
                android:type="linear" />
            <corners android:radius="100dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

---

[Here is a preview image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbGrS.png)

---

try this

Comment: The shape is right, but It doesn't work with the fixed height and width.
When I use this drawable as background for a textview, it forces his height and width.
I could change those values but I want the drawable to be usable in different places

Comment: Can you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061387/android-drawable-specifying-shape-width-in-percent-in-the-xml-file

It may be helpful for you