# How do I define a custom view attribute that can take multiple enums?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-xml

I want to create a custom view attribute that can take one or more values, OR-ed:

```
app:myAttribute="foo|bar"
```

Basically just like `android:gravity`:

```
android:gravity="left|bottom"
```

Comment: check it out: https://medium.com/@elye.project/better-way-of-declaring-custom-view-attributes-23f876c28534

Comment: Rad Haring's have a really good post about it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22362100/6322621