# How to read custom attributes in Android

Tags: java, android, android-custom-view

I can create custom attributes and apply them to regular `EditTexts`, like this:

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/field1"
     custom:attr1="whatever"
     (...)
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/field2"
     custom:attr1="whatever2"
     (...)
```

My question: can I read the value of those custom attributes without creating a class that extends `EditText`? I mean, I want to read custom attributes from my `Activity`, but the examples I see so far requires me to read the values from the constructor of a custom view, like here: [Defining custom attrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs)

Comment: no, you cant do this. AttributeSet throws away after view construction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> My question: can I read the value of those custom attributes without
>   creating a class that extends EditText?

Yes, you can get those attributes without extending the classes. For this you could use a special `Factory` set on the `LayoutInflater` that the `Activity` will use to parse the layout files. Something like this:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new CustomAttrFactory());
setContentView(R.layout.the_layout);
```

where the `CustomAttrFactory` is like this:

```
public static class CustomAttrFactory implements Factory {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
            AttributeSet attrs) {
        String attributeValue = attrs
                .getAttributeValue(
                        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.luksprog.droidproj1",
                        "attrnew");
        Log.e("ZXX", "" + attributeValue);
        // if attributeValue is non null then you know the attribute is
        // present on this view(you can use the name to identify the view,
        // or its id attribute)
        return null;
    }
}
```

The idea comes from a [blog post](http://sergiandreplace.com/blog/2012/11/15/dealing-with-fonts-and-inflaters-in-android/), you may want to read it for additional information.

Also, depending on that custom attribute(or attributes if you have other) you could just use `android:tag="whatever"` to pass the additional data(and later retrieve it in the `Activity` with `view.getTag()`).

I would advise you to not use those custom attributes and rethink your current approach.

Comment: I like the idea of the factory. Thank you!

Comment: and here it go :-( the link is broken now.

Comment: @Nicks That's the problem with providing outside links, sorry. However, in that blog post it was mostly the same information that I provided in my answer related to the custom factory used with a LayoutInflater.

Comment: @Luksprog  but thanks a lot, your added description is enough to track and solve :-) Thanks a lot. I hope this will work with fragments too.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say no, you can't. I checked sources of `EditText` and it parents and didn't found place where it stores custom atributes to instance property so you can use them later. So I think you need to create your own class that extends `EditText`.

Comment: I know I could parse the xml layout and read the values from there, but there must be some easier way...

Comment: @André yes, create your own class :) Why don't you want to create separate class?

Comment: because I want to apply the same attributes to edittexts, spinners, checkboxes etc. I don't want to create a custom class for each field type