# Android custom attribute for TextView

Tags: java, android, attributes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read custom attributes in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339333/how-to-read-custom-attributes-in-android)

Recently I read about custom attributes. I want to add a custom attribute to TextView.

So far I have:

attr file:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="binding" format="string" />
    <declare-styleable name="TextView">
        <attr name="binding" />
    </declare-styleable>
```

layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/de.innosoft.android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            custom:binding="test"/>
```

Given a TextView

```
TextView tv = ...
```

How would I then get the value of that attribute (which ist "test")? I read about obtainStyledAttributes but do not know exactly how to use it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I know you have 2 options:

- Create your own view that extends `TextView` and has constructor that takes `AttributeSet`. Then you can get custom property in this constructor. Check this tutorial: [Creating a View Class](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html).
- Implement own [LayoutInfalter.Factory](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) where you handle custom attributes.

Better check this question: [How to read custom attributes in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339333/how-to-read-custom-attributes-in-android) it's almost the same.

Comment: thank you very much vor the link to the other post. Seems I need that. But still I don't know how to get the custom attribute value e.g. for a textview. (with obtainStyledAttributes ?)

Comment: @cdbeelala89 check tutorial I mentioned in answer. Bacically you create calss `MyTextView` that extends `TextView` and implement constructor that takes context and attributes  and use `obtainStyledAttributes` to ge thandy `TypedArray`.

Comment: How can we set a custom attribute value programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

Exactly, you can extend your textview like that

```
 public class CustomTV extends TextView {

 public final String YOURATTRS;

 public CustomTV(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
            TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomTV);
    YOURATTRS = ta.getString(R.styleable.CustomTV_binding);
    ta.recycle();

 // use your attrs or not
 }
```

and the attrs.xml :

```
<declare-styleable name="CustomTV">
     <attr name="binding" format="string"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

Comment: any idea why I always have custom attribute as null?