# Android XML custom attribute always returning the default value

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, attr

I'm trying to implement a custom attribute for my custom TextView class. I followed the [Creating a View Class](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html) by the letter and went through questions here like

- [Android custom attribute for TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360645/android-custom-attribute-for-textview)
- [How to read custom attributes in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339333/how-to-read-custom-attributes-in-android)

and few more. They are all the same and they all failed to help me in this case!

so here are some of my code **attr** ( i added the first part

```
 <declare-styleable name="AvatarImageBehavior">
    <attr name="finalYPosition" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="startXPosition" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="startToolbarPosition" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="startHeight" format="dimension"/>
    <attr name="finalHeight" format="dimension"/>
</declare-styleable>

     <declare-styleable name="CustomFont">
            <attr name="toPersianNumbers" format="boolean" />
            <attr name="cFontWeight" format="enum">
                <enum name="thin" value="0"/>
                <enum name="normal" value="1"/>
                <enum name="bold" value="2"/>
            </attr>
        </declare-styleable>
```

**xml**

```
    <com.sahab.omida.sahab.visualImprovements.AppCompact.TextViewPlus
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="@string/load_sub_pickup_location"
                                custom:cFontWeight="bold"
                                android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
                                android:textColor="?titleColor"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

**function**

        public static int fontWeight(AttributeSet attrs, Context ctx, int defStyle){
        TypedArray a = ctx.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(
                attrs,
                R.styleable.CustomFont,
                defStyle, 0);
        int fontWeight;
        try {
            fontWeight = a.getInteger(R.styleable.CustomFont_cFontWeight,1);
            Log.d("fontweight", "fontWeight: " + fontWeight);
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
        return fontWeight;
    }

and **one of my constructors**

        public TextViewPlus(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        this.ctx = context;
        this.lang = SharedPreferenceHelper.getLang(context);
        this.fontWeight = CustomFontsLoader.fontWeight(attrs,ctx,defStyle);
        init();
    }
```

the following is in the other constructor containing attrs

```
this.fontWeight = CustomFontsLoader.fontWeight(attrs,ctx,0);
```

that must be all. it must be something small that I missed. but I just can't get it to work no matter how I check it.

ps. TextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

Comment: Does your two-parameter constructor also do the same setup? What's the namespace you've defined for the `custom` prefix?

Comment: yes it does. and `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

Comment: Yeah, wrong namespace. It should be `xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`.

Comment: thanks. it was automatically added by the android studio so I didn't check the namespace, it's all working now

Comment: No problem. Btw, the `tools` namespace in a layout is for design-time features. You might still need that, if want things to look a certain way in the editor: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: I think you need to correct tow point：

 1. By convention, the custom view (TextViewPlus) and the declare-styleable (CustomFont) should have the same name (various editor features rely on this convention);
 2. You'd better use xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto", **custom:cFontWeight** change to **app:cFontWeight**.