# Retrieve information on custom attributes in Android

Tags: android

I want to retrieve some information about custom attributes defined inside the 'attrs.xml' resource file of some library. In detail, I want to get the name and the format of all attributes.

I searched the documentation but I didn't find any example on how to do this. I only found examples on how to retrieve the values of these attributes inside a constructor of a custom view.

For example, given the following XML resource file.

```xml
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="PieChart">
       <attr name="showText" format="boolean" />
       <attr name="labelPosition" format="enum">
           <enum name="left" value="0"/>
           <enum name="right" value="1"/>
       </attr>
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I want to get the list of attributes with their names and types. Something like this.

```
Attribute name: showText, type: boolean
Attribute name: labelPosition, type: enum {left, right}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try a special `Factory` set on the `LayoutInflater` that the `Activity` will use to parse the layout files.

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new CustomAttrFactory());
setContentView(R.layout.the_layout);
```

where the `CustomAttrFactory` is like this:

```
public static class CustomAttrFactory implements Factory {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
            AttributeSet attrs) {
        String attributeValue = attrs
                .getAttributeValue(
                        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.luksprog.droidproj1",
                        "attrnew");
        Log.e("ZXX", "" + attributeValue);
        // if attributeValue is non null then you know the attribute is
        // present on this view(you can use the name to identify the view,
        // or its id attribute)
        return null;
    }
}
```

Refer here for more [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339333/how-to-read-custom-attributes-in-android) .

Hope it helps !

Comment: This is not what I want to achieve. I want to read these attributes from the resources files and not their values.