# Accessing Custom Attribute without extending the view and not using the CustomAttrFactory in every Activity

Tags: android, xml

I am trying to read the custom attribute without extending the View. I am following this post:-
[How to read custom attributes in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14339333/how-to-read-custom-attributes-in-android/60636831#60636831)

Is it possible to add this in only one activity? or this is needed to be added whereever the custom attributes are needed to be fetched?

```
public abstract class BaseDialog extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public void onViewCreated(final View view, @Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new CustomAttrFactory());
}

public static class CustomAttrFactory implements LayoutInflater.Factory {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
                             AttributeSet attrs) {
        String attributeValue = attrs
                .getAttributeValue(
                        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto",
                        "stringId");
        System.out.println("Attribute obtained using this method/" + attributeValue);
        // if attributeValue is non null then you know the attribute is
        // present on this view(you can use the name to identify the view,
        // or its id attribute)
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above implementation is not working for me.

Comment: Yes, it does need to be in every `Activity` where you need to do that. However, you could create a base `Activity` class that all of your other Activities extend, and set the `Factory` there, so you aren't repeating code in each one.

Comment: @MikeM. My use case is where I will specify the string Id in custom attribute for which I need to call a function to get the translation for the same. Now for all the views that are specified in the layout, I have to call this function. Will this be possible using the above implementation?

Comment: Sure will. In fact, now that I think about it, you don't even need to set a `Factory` yourself. `Activity` is already a `Factory` for its own `LayoutInflater`, so in your `BaseActivity`, for example, simply override `onCreateView()`, and do your translation lookup there. Then, for each `Activity` that needs that behavior, simply subclass that base; e.g., `public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity`.

Comment: I should mention that there will actually be two `onCreateView()` methods that you can override in `Activity`; one like that shown in Luksprog's answer, and another one that has an additional `View parent` parameter. Either one will work (unless you're running on a super-ancient Android version, which is unlikely), so pick whichever you feel is appropriate for your use.

Comment: @MikeM.  but suppose I have two Buttons in a layout, how will the translation occur for both of them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I don't really know the details of what you're trying to do. I was simply telling you how to use that `Factory` method in all of your `Activity` classes, per the stated question.

Comment: @MikeM., SO here is amn example: - The factory Method will be used to fetch the custom attribute of all the TextViews in the activity for which I will call a method. Now my question is how to access all of those attributes and change them when I have only one overridden OnCreateView.

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're asking, but `onCreateView()` will be called separately for each individual tag that the `LayoutInflater` encounters. For example, say your layout is a `LinearLayout` with two `Button`s. `onCreateView()` will be called three times: once for the `LinearLayout`, then once for the first `Button`, and once more for the second `Button`. It's not like `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()`, which is called only once for the whole thing, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @MikeM., I am trying to implement this in BaseDialog that extends DialogFragment and this BaseDialog is used by each of my Dialog boxes. But this is not running for this Dialog. I am overriding the onViewCreated method of DialogFragment. Details updated above.