# Location(s) of the COMPLETE definitions of Android XML tags?

Tags: android

I know this is an old question and there had been some very impressive answers already like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs).

So the closest answer is the [attrs.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml) in the source or the [android.R.styleable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html) class in the SDK reference. However I've found it still incomplete, for example, the `<RadioButton>` tag. It seems that the attributes possessed by `RadioButton` are all inherited from its ancestors, so the definition for its own tag was totally ignored, or maybe it was defined elsewhere.

Any idea about where it was defined and the complete locations of all the tag definitions?

Thanks