# declare properties with same name but different types

Tags: android, eclipse, android-custom-view, custom-view

I am trying to declare properties for to different classes some of the properties have the same name but different types on different classes. Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="net.firouz.mastergardner.IntEditView">
        <attr name="caption" format="string" />
        <attr name="min_val" format="integer" />
        <attr name="max_val" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="net.firouz.mastergardner.FloatEditView">
        <attr name="min_val" format="float" />
        <attr name="max_val" format="float" />
    </declare-styleable>    
</resources>
```

but eclipse complains that the attributes `max_val` and `min_val` have already been defined. How can I fix this.

Thank you
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better answer with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs) posting.
Apparently attributes can have multiple formats which makes the following code valid and can work for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="min_val" format="float|integer|reference" />
    <attr name="max_val" format="float|integer|reference" />
    <declare-styleable name="IntEditView">
        <attr name="Caption" format="string|reference" />
        <attr name="min_val" />
        <attr name="max_val" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="FloatEditView">
        <attr name="min_val" />
        <attr name="max_val" />
    </declare-styleable>    
</resources>
```

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 3):

You can go with either of below 2 solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<attr name="min_val" format="float" />
<attr name="max_val" format="float" />
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="net.firouz.mastergardner.IntEditView">
        <attr name="caption" format="string" />
        <attr name="min_val" />
        <attr name="max_val" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="net.firouz.mastergardner.FloatEditView">
        <attr name="min_val" />
        <attr name="max_val" />
    </declare-styleable>    
</resources>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="net.firouz.mastergardner.IntEditView">
        <attr name="caption" format="string" />
        <attr name="min_val_i" format="integer" />
        <attr name="max_val_i" format="integer" />
    </declare-styleable>
    <declare-styleable name="net.firouz.mastergardner.FloatEditView">
        <attr name="min_val_f" format="float" />
        <attr name="max_val_f" format="float" />
    </declare-styleable>    
</resources>
```

android generated only one class for all attributes "R.attr", and as min_val and max_val were already defined as integer eclipse complain next time it sees its declaration as float.

Comment: I think I have to go with the second method because on the first one both of the become float which is not what I am looking for.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. It seems that android pre-pends the styleable name to the property name. in my case it produces net_firouz_mastergardner_IntEditView_min_val and net_firouz_mastergardner_IntEditView_max_val and net_firouz_mastergardner_FloatEditView_min_val and net_firouz_mastergardner_FloatEditView_max_val which are not the same thing. could this be a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Add  your attributes directly as children of the  node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="min_val" format="float" />
    <attr name="max_val" format="float" />

    <declare-styleable name="net.firouz.mastergardner.IntEditView">
       <attr name="caption" format="string" />
       <attr name="min_val" />
       <attr name="max_val"/>
   </declare-styleable>

   <declare-styleable name="net.firouz.mastergardner.FloatEditView">
      <attr name="min_val" />
      <attr name="max_val"/>
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Else you have to use different attribute names for your float and integer attribute

Comment: for IntEditView I need integer and for FloatEditView I need float. With your method both will get float.