# How to screenshot or snapshot a view before it's rendered?

Tags: java, android, view, bitmap, screenshot

I want to create an image of a view before it's rendered as a preview.

I tried [Take a screenshot of a whole View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791714/take-a-screenshot-of-a-whole-view) 
but the problem is that it gives a blank bitmap because the view was not rendered at that time.

I also tried drawing cache, but it gives me a blank bitmap as well.

Is there anyway that I can create an image of a view before it's rendered on the screen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cant take a screenshot of something which is not rendered on the screen.

Comment: Render it as hidden, snap the shot then display.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18565467/2211156

Comment: Check answer in this post, i found some kind of solution:  [Save multiple TextViews as image of large resolution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36424381/save-multiple-textviews-as-image-of-large-resolution/36455437#36455437)

Answer (score 0):

Every `View` class support the creating of an image of its current display. The following coding shows an example for that.

```
# Build the Drawing Cache
view.buildDrawingCache();

# Create Bitmap
Bitmap cache = view.getDrawingCache();

# Save Bitmap
saveBitmap(cache);
view.destroyDrawingCache();
```

And it is not possible to take a screenshot of a view before it's rendered.