# Android inflate view not honoring dynamically set width

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-notifications, android-inflate

I'm trying to generate a `bitmap` to show in the notification. The layout is a bit complex, however, I need to set the width according to the screen size. In the XML, I have a `LinearLayout` in the root and I inflate the view with

```
  LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) i inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_expanded_detail, null, false);
```

This layout has quite a bunch of elements which I need to fill. And their width depends on the width of the layout itself and the width of the layout varies with phone. I set the width for the inflated layout with

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) available_width, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
v.setLayoutParams(params);
```

However, when I try to generate a `bitmap` from this, it appears that the size set with the `setLayoutParams` is not affecting the child views of the inflated layout. There are many questions around i in SO, however, all of them deals with inflating a layout that already has a `rootView` and nothing worked for me. A couple of answers suggested that I call the `measure()` method on the view. However, after calling the measure method, the `getMeasuredWidth` returns a width lesser that what I had set with the `setLayoutParams` call.

### Update

A little more context about the problem. I was trying to show a notification that had a placeholder ImageView which I would later fill in with a bitmap generated from a view inflated from an XML. The remote view layout is

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sliderViewBottom"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="256dp"
android:background="@color/detail_page_blue"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="false"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="10dp"
>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/progressImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#D05757"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/overAllDelay"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Delayed by "
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/overAllDelayVal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/overAllDelay"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

The layout that I was trying to inflate and generate a bitmap from to set in the `progressImage` was

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_page_track_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/swipe_layout_info_card_track_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/swipe_layout_info_card_track_margin"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fromGreenCircle"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/from_green_circle"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:src="@drawable/station_end"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4.5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/swipe_page_empty_track"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fromGreenTrack"
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="4.5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/from_green_track"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/trackNavigationIcon"
        android:layout_width="12dp"
        android:layout_height="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_track_detail_card_current_station_pointer"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/currentStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/trackNavigationIcon"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I was trying to inflate this second layout with

```
  LinearLayout v = (LinearLayout) i inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_expanded_detail, null, false);
```

And then was using

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams((int) available_width, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
v.setLayoutParams(params);
```

This available_width was computed dynamically. However, when I later tried to generate a Bitmap from this inflated view by using `v.layout()`, it kep t generating an image which was not honouring the width that I set.

Later, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565226/programmaticaly-inflate-view-with-pre-defined-measures?rq=1) SO thread where I noticed that while inflating, instead of specifying null as the parentView, `new LinearLayoutParams(contex)` was specified. I tried that and now, the dynamically set width is being honoured.

Comment: Is this for a status bar notification?

Comment: It's for setting the bigContentView in notifications. Thanks

Comment: Then I don't understand your question. Status bar notification UI is configured using `RemoteViews`, not through normal view inflation and modification. Perhaps you should clarify what you are asking and include additional code snippets.

Comment: Yes, I am using RemoteViews. In that remote view, i have an imageView which i generate from generating a bitmap by inflating another layout and filling content in it. Later I set that bitmap into that image view. I just saw another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18565226/programmaticaly-inflate-view-with-pre-defined-measures?rq=1 and noticed that while inflating, we give new LinearLayout(context) as the rootView. I tried the same and it's not working! Thanks much for your help :)

Comment: Please include more relevant code snippets. There is no way to tell what (or if) you are doing anything different than the link you just posted. At the very least, it would be helpful to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41190509/edit) your post and include that link if that is exactly the code you are using.

Comment: I've included more code snippets and have tried to elaborate on the question. Hope it would help someone some day. Thanks much for the help again!

Comment: Based on your edit, it sounds like your issue is resolved?

Comment: Yes, I saw the other SO thread just minutes after posting this question. I got that question in the related section of this question! Funny how I never encountered that question while Googling  :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this SO thread where I noticed that while inflating, instead of specifying null as the parentView, new LinearLayoutParams(contex) was specified. I tried that and now, the dynamically set width is being honoured