# Android - Create Custom View

Tags: android, android-view

I want to create a custom view a thing like a power switch ( a switch that switches between ON and OFF). When I have started to implement it I faced 3 constructors for `View` class:

```
public CusatomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}
```

Now my question is: Which one of these constructors I should complete it to retrieve my own XML attribute (for instance: `textOn` and `textOff`)?
And what is the role of each?

Comment: Check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681956/setting-color-of-a-paint-object-in-custom-view. Also read Professional Android DEvelopment By Reto Meier. Chapter 3.

Comment: @Raghunandan thanks for your link, it's helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, you should do your stuff in a separate method and call this from all three constructors, because you never know which of the constructor will be called. Here are the roles:

1. `CusatomView(Context context)` creates a new view with no attributes initialized.
2. `CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)` is invoked when you set attributes like `layout_height` or `layout_width` in your `layout.xml`
3. `CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)` is used when you set styles to your view.

Answer (score 0):

You should create another funciton `init` and call it in all.

```
public CusatomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public CustomView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}
```

The thing is any of this constructors can be used to instantiate your custom view. As in when you create a view in java code you just provide context and when it is created from xml attrs is also supplied.