# Set textcolor and other attribute in textview extends

Tags: android

How can i set text color and text size in the class below

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {
    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }
    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }
    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }
    public void init() {
        Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/chiller.ttf");
        setTypeface(tf ,1);
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `init` use `setTextColor` and `setTextSize`

```
  public void init() {
    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "font/chiller.ttf");
    setTypeface(tf ,1);
    this.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    this.setTextSize(20f);
}
```

If you are looking for custom attributes check this

[Setting color of a Paint object in custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681956/setting-color-of-a-paint-object-in-custom-view)