# FATAL EXCEPTION MAIN error / Error Inflating class - Android

Tags: android, fatal-error, layout-inflater

Currently I am working on android application in which I need to use sliding drawer.
I am following this [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=16622).

When I try to run my application It give me an error.

By analyze logcat I found this error.

```
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.panel/org.panel.Test}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class org.panel.SmoothButton
```

This show error at oncreate at Test.java

```
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at org.panel.Test.onCreate(Test.java:30)
```

This shows error in smoothButton.java

```
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at org.panel.SmoothButton.<init>(SmoothButton.java:43)
```

at this place in smoothButton.java

```
if (transitionDrawable == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("transitionDrawable must be defined in XML (with valid xmlns)");
    }
```

So how to solve this error. Thanks for your help.

Complete logcat

```
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401): Process: org.panel, PID: 5401
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.panel/org.panel.Test}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class org.panel.SmoothButton
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #56: Error inflating class org.panel.SmoothButton
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at org.panel.Test.onCreate(Test.java:30)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     ... 11 more
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     ... 23 more
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: transitionDrawable must be defined in XML (with valid xmlns)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     at org.panel.SmoothButton.<init>(SmoothButton.java:43)
04-28 06:33:01.155: E/AndroidRuntime(5401):     ... 26 more
```

Test.java class

```
package org.panel;

import org.panel.Panel.OnPanelListener;

import easing.interpolator.BackInterpolator;
import easing.interpolator.BounceInterpolator;
import easing.interpolator.ElasticInterpolator;
import easing.interpolator.ExpoInterpolator;
import easing.interpolator.EasingType.Type;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Test extends Activity implements OnPanelListener {

private Panel bottomPanel;
private Panel topPanel;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Panel panel;

    topPanel = panel = (Panel) findViewById(R.id.topPanel);
    panel.setOnPanelListener(this);
    panel.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator(Type.OUT));

    panel = (Panel) findViewById(R.id.leftPanel1);
    panel.setOnPanelListener(this);
    panel.setInterpolator(new BackInterpolator(Type.OUT, 2));

    panel = (Panel) findViewById(R.id.leftPanel2);
    panel.setOnPanelListener(this);
    panel.setInterpolator(new BackInterpolator(Type.OUT, 2));

    panel = (Panel) findViewById(R.id.rightPanel);
    panel.setOnPanelListener(this);
    panel.setInterpolator(new ExpoInterpolator(Type.OUT));

    bottomPanel = panel = (Panel) findViewById(R.id.bottomPanel);
    panel.setOnPanelListener(this);
    panel.setInterpolator(new ElasticInterpolator(Type.OUT, 1.0f, 0.3f));

    findViewById(R.id.smoothButton1).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bottomPanel.setOpen(!bottomPanel.isOpen(), true);
        }
    });
    findViewById(R.id.smoothButton2).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            topPanel.setOpen(!topPanel.isOpen(), false);
        }
    });
}

public void onPanelClosed(Panel panel) {
    String panelName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(panel.getId());
    Log.d("Test", "Panel [" + panelName + "] closed");
}
public void onPanelOpened(Panel panel) {
    String panelName = getResources().getResourceEntryName(panel.getId());
    Log.d("Test", "Panel [" + panelName + "] opened");
}
}
```

This is SmoothButton.java

```
package org.panel;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.LevelListDrawable;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SmoothButton extends Button {

private static final long DELAY = 25;

private LevelListDrawable transitionDrawable;
private int transitionDrawableLength;
private int level;

private int[] colors;

public SmoothButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.SmoothButton);
    transitionDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) a.getDrawable(R.styleable.SmoothButton_transitionDrawable);
    transitionDrawableLength = a.getInt(R.styleable.SmoothButton_transitionDrawableLength, 0);
    int useTextColors = 0;
    int c0 = 0;
    if (a.hasValue(R.styleable.SmoothButton_transitionTextColorUp)) {
        c0 = a.getColor(R.styleable.SmoothButton_transitionTextColorUp, 0);
        useTextColors++;
    }
    int c1 = 0;
    if (useTextColors == 1 && a.hasValue(R.styleable.SmoothButton_transitionTextColorDown)) {
        c1 = a.getColor(R.styleable.SmoothButton_transitionTextColorDown, 0);
        useTextColors++;
    }
    a.recycle();

    if (transitionDrawable == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("transitionDrawable must be defined in XML (with valid xmlns)");
    }
    if (transitionDrawableLength == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("transitionDrawableLength must be defined in XML (with valid xmlns)");
    }
    if (useTextColors == 2) {
        setTextColor(c0);
        int a0 = Color.alpha(c0);
        int r0 = Color.red(c0);
        int g0 = Color.green(c0);
        int b0 = Color.blue(c0);
        int a1 = Color.alpha(c1);
        int r1 = Color.red(c1);
        int g1 = Color.green(c1);
        int b1 = Color.blue(c1);
        colors = new int[transitionDrawableLength];
        for (int i=0; i<transitionDrawableLength; i++) {
            int ai = a0 + i * (a1 - a0) / transitionDrawableLength;
            int ri = r0 + i * (r1 - r0) / transitionDrawableLength;
            int gi = g0 + i * (g1 - g0) / transitionDrawableLength;
            int bi = b0 + i * (b1 - b0) / transitionDrawableLength;
            colors[i] = Color.argb(ai, ri, gi, bi);
        }
    }
    level = 0;
    transitionDrawable.setLevel(level);
    int paddingLeft = getPaddingLeft();
    int paddingTop = getPaddingTop();
    int paddingRight = getPaddingRight();
    int paddingBottom = getPaddingBottom();
    setBackgroundDrawable(transitionDrawable);
    setPadding(paddingLeft, paddingTop, paddingRight, paddingBottom);
}

@Override
protected void drawableStateChanged() {
    super.drawableStateChanged();
    int delta = isPressed()? 1 : -1;
    handler.removeMessages(-delta);
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(delta);
}

private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        int what = msg.what;

        level += what;
        if (level >= 0 && level < transitionDrawableLength) {
            transitionDrawable.setLevel(level);
            if (colors != null) {
                setTextColor(colors[level]);
            }
            handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(what, DELAY);
        } else {
            level = Math.max(0, level);
            level = Math.min(transitionDrawableLength-1, level);
        }
    }
};

public void setTransitionDrawable(Drawable drawable, int length) {
    transitionDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) drawable;
    transitionDrawableLength = length;
    level = 0;
    invalidate();
}
}
```

This is main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/src/org.panel"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#767c9b">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <org.panel.Panel
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/topPanel" 
        android:paddingBottom="20dip"
        panel:position="top"
        panel:animationDuration="1000"
        panel:linearFlying="true"
        panel:openedHandle="@drawable/top_switcher_expanded_background"
        panel:closedHandle="@drawable/top_switcher_collapsed_background"
    >
        <Button
            android:id="@id/panelHandle" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="33dip" 
        />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/panelContent" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="60dip" 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="top check box"
                android:background="#688"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Bounce\nInterpolator"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:padding="4dip"
                android:textColor="#eee"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="#323299"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </org.panel.Panel>
    <org.panel.SmoothButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/smoothButton1" 
        android:text="click me and see bottom panel..."
        android:textStyle="bold"
        panel:transitionDrawable="@drawable/transition_list"
        panel:transitionDrawableLength="8"
        panel:transitionTextColorUp="#eee"
        panel:transitionTextColorDown="#aaa"
    />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"> 
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:textSize="16dip"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:paddingLeft="45dip"
            android:paddingRight="45dip"
            android:textColor="#ddd"
            android:text="Central area\n\nTry to use panels on each side of me\n\nEvery panel has its own interpolator\n\nLeft/Right panels are overlayed"
        />
    </ScrollView>
    <org.panel.SmoothButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/smoothButton2" 
        android:text="click me and see top panel..."
        android:textStyle="bold"
        panel:transitionDrawable="@drawable/transition_list"
        panel:transitionDrawableLength="8"
        panel:transitionTextColorUp="#eee"
        panel:transitionTextColorDown="#aaa"
    />
    <org.panel.Panel
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/bottomPanel"
        android:paddingTop="20dip"  
        panel:position="bottom"
        panel:animationDuration="1200"
        panel:openedHandle="@drawable/bottom_switcher_expanded_background"
        panel:closedHandle="@drawable/bottom_switcher_collapsed_background"
    >
        <Button
            android:id="@id/panelHandle" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="33dip" 
        />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/panelContent" 
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Elastic\nInterpolator"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:padding="4dip"
                android:textColor="#eee"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:background="#993333"
            />
            <CheckBox
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="60dip" 
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="bottom check box"
                android:background="#688"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </org.panel.Panel>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
    <org.panel.Panel
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/leftPanel1" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        panel:position="left"
        panel:openedHandle="@drawable/left_switcher_expanded_background"
        panel:closedHandle="@drawable/left_switcher_collapsed_background"
    >
        <Button
            android:id="@id/panelHandle" 
            android:layout_width="33dip" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/panelContent" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dip"
            android:text="This is\nmy first\nleft Panel"
            android:textSize="16dip"
            android:textColor="#eee"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#999932"
        />
    </org.panel.Panel>
    <org.panel.Panel
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/leftPanel2" 
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        panel:position="left"
        panel:openedHandle="@drawable/left_switcher_expanded_background"
        panel:closedHandle="@drawable/left_switcher_collapsed_background"
    >
        <Button
            android:id="@id/panelHandle" 
            android:layout_width="33dip" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@id/panelContent" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dip"
            android:text="This is\nmy second\nleft Panel"
            android:textSize="16dip"
            android:textColor="#eee"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:background="#115544"
        />
    </org.panel.Panel>
</LinearLayout>
<org.panel.Panel
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/rightPanel"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    panel:position="right"
    panel:openedHandle="@drawable/right_switcher_expanded_background"
    panel:closedHandle="@drawable/right_switcher_collapsed_background"
>
    <Button
        android:id="@id/panelHandle" 
        android:layout_width="33dip" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@id/panelContent" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:text="Expo\nInterpolator"
        android:textSize="16dip"
        android:textColor="#eee"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#329999"
    />
</org.panel.Panel>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: have this `xmlns:panel="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.panel"` as the namespace and try and it looks like you are having custom attributes

Comment: also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681956/setting-color-of-a-paint-object-in-custom-view

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks brother you save my life. I need to put `res` in place of `src` in namespace. Now its working fine. Thanks.