# get attribute programmatically (NOT in a view, but everywhere)

Tags: android, attributes

I've defined an attribute (and I set it in my theme)

```
<attr name="primaryColor" format="color|reference" />
```

how can I get the color in the code? I tried `getResources().getColor(R.attr.primaryColor)` but this fails...

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3441986/983741

Comment: I dont't have an `AttributeSet` if I'm not in the constructor of a custom view... So this solution does not help me... I want to find out the color that is defined in the current theme... Anywhere, not only in the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
Need a Context.

```
TypedValue typeValue = new TypedValue();
context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.primaryColor, typeValue, true);
if (typeValue.type >= TypedValue.TYPE_FIRST_COLOR_INT &&
    typeValue.type <= TypedValue.TYPE_LAST_COLOR_INT) {
    // R.attr.primaryColor is a color
    int color = typeValue.data;
} else {
    // R.attr.primaryColor is not a color

}
```