# Superpose many image View on an ImageView in a customView

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-custom-view

I would like to create a view in android that componsed of an `ImageView` and a `TextView` upon this `ImageView`. But the Custom views that we can create in Android contain attributes that can only be of certain types, as specified in this post : [Defining custom attrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs) So I can't define a custom view with an `ImageView` attribute and a `TextView` attribute. 
I don't want to define it this way neither :

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/card_11"
         android:layout_width="@dimen/card_width"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
         android:src="@drawable/carte_vierge_bleue"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:clickable="true" 
         android:visibility="visible"
         android:onClick="onCardClicked"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1234 5678 1234 5678"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Because I would like to add other images on the first `ImageView` after that so I would like to have a custom view that I can modify however I want, and add on it as many `ImageView`s as I want, and this way of doing would make the layout file very long...
Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understood correctly, you can use a *RelativeLayout* with as many ImageViews as you want.
For example:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/card_11"
         android:layout_width="@dimen/card_width"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
         android:src="@drawable/carte_vierge_bleue"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:clickable="true" 
         android:visibility="visible"
         android:onClick="onCardClicked"/>

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/card_12"
         android:layout_width="@dimen/card_width"
         android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
         android:src="@drawable/carte_vierge_bleue"
         android:scaleType="fitXY"
         android:clickable="true" 
         android:visibility="visible"
         android:onClick="onCardClicked"/>

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1234 5678 1234 5678"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The TextView will be displayed on top of *card12 ImageView*, which will be displayed on top of *card11 ImageView* and so on.

Hope it helped, Mattia

Comment: Yes, you are right, it worked. I am just wondering how can I display the textView in the center of the view since it is displayed on the top of it, even with the attribute gravity set to center ?

Comment: You are in a RelativeLayout you can't use the gravity attribute, you must you _centerInParent="true"_.