# How do you pass the gravity attribute via xml for a custom view?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-custom-view

I'm trying to figure out how to pass `android:gravity` via xml for a custom view.

The solution posted here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/3441986/413254) says to add the `android:gravity` attribute to the other attr's.

When I do this, I end up with a warning saying:

> /Users/greg/dev/company/mobile/my_app/app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml
>
> Error:Attribute "android:gravity" has already been defined
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processStagingDebugResources'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
> >         /Users/greg/dev/android-sdk/sdk/build-tools/21.0.2/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/greg/dev/android-sdk/sdk/platforms/android-21/android.jar -M
> >     /Users/greg/dev/company/mobile/myapp/app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/staging/debug/AndroidManifest.xml
> >     -S /Users/greg/dev/company/mobile/myapp/app/build/intermediates/res/staging/debug
> >     -A /Users/greg/dev/company/mobile/myapp/app/build/intermediates/assets/staging/debug
> >     -m -J /Users/greg/dev/company/mobile/myapp/app/build/generated/source/r/staging/debug
> >     -F /Users/greg/dev/company/mobile/myapp/app/build/intermediates/res/resources-staging-debug.ap_
> >     --debug-mode --custom-package com.company.vendorreviews -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/greg/dev/company/mobile/myapp/app/build/intermediates/symbols/staging/debug
> >     Error Code:
> >         1   Output:
> >         /Users/greg/dev/company/mobile/myapp/app/build/intermediates/res/staging/debug/values/values.xml:165:
> >     error: Attribute "android:gravity" has already been defined

My colors.xml file?

Line 165 of values.xml is

```
<declare-styleable name="StackedTextView">
    <attr format="integer" name="android:gravity"/>
    <attr format="string" name="line1"/>
    <attr format="string" name="line2"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="line1_textSize"/>
    <attr format="dimension" name="line2_textSize"/>
</declare-styleable>
```

There are multiple occurrences of android:gravity in multiple  groups. Theme, FlowLayout (library I include), LinearLayoutCompat, etc.

Edit: Updated error message.

Comment: that works for me: <attr name="android:gravity" /> inside <declare-styleable> tag

Comment: Hm... it's happening for my colors.xml?? Updating with the full error

Comment: post values.xml line 165 and surrounding lines with line numbers then

Comment: Updated. I don't believe the surrounding lines would be terribly relevant.

Comment: remove the format attribute

Comment: Doh! Thanks. If you want to answer officially, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

by writing:

```
<attr format="integer" name="android:gravity"/>
```

you are intruducing the new attribute `android:gravity` with integer format, of course `android:gravity` is already defined in the system, so you need to change it into:

```
<attr name="android:gravity"/>
```