# Android R file wont show up. I imported pictures into drawable with the wrong format that messed up every single one of my projects

Tags: java, android, file

In every single one of my projects I have an error in res-value-styles.

I imported a shortcut to a picture in my drawables and now I dont have an R file and I get an error on every line. I have done corrections i have seen online to minimize the errors in the res folder. (Changing values in the 3 values folders) Now my only error  in the res folder is with my main.xml.  Here it is below.  Keep in mind that I have just started a new project so all this code was given.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.quigg.muffin2.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

I have an error to the left of item that says "error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package".

Anybody know what this error means and or how to fix this?

Comment: I am programming in Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

You do not need a custom attributes in your XML.

Remove the lines

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

and change the line

```
app:showAsAction="never"
```

to

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

[Defining custom attrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs)