# Reuse custom View's code without the text label

Tags: android

I have created a custom view by extending the TextView widget.
What it basically does is a Round view with some text above the Circle which acts as a background.

Now I need the same view again but without the text. Is there a way I can reuse the same code - instead of just copy/paste the code to create a View class without the text?

The onDraw code with the text is :

```
    @Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawCircle(150, 150, 150, paintBG);
    canvas.drawText("Some Text", 0, 150, textPaint);
}
```

EDIT :
what i need is some kind of an if statement where the drawtext happens. 
If my view needs the text label then use the drawText. I just don't know what the condition should be since I use the code to my xml layout file.

Comment: I would actually just not hardcode "some text" and make it a variable instead.  Then if you want to make the text invisible either pass in a null or blank. Then simply don't draw it if it's null or blank.

Comment: Or have a "showText" boolean value or something.  There's a number of ways.

Comment: showText is what i did and works. I added a method :     public void showText(Boolean showText) {  this.showText = showText;  }
and in onCreate I set it to false for the view i dont need the text. I just thought I could have done this in the xml code.

Comment: You can actually do it in xml code using custom attributes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write a custom Drawable class instead. Then you can make an instance at runtime and set it as the background of whatever View you like.

```
public class MyDrawable extends Drawable {

    boolean drawText;
    // other members, constructors, etc

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawCircle(150, 150, 150, paintBG);
        if (drawText) {
            canvas.drawText("Some Text", 0, 150, textPaint);
        }
    }

    // other methods
}

MyDrawable d = new MyDrawable();
mTextView.setBackground(d);
```