# How to use namespace "app" in a style?

Tags: android

In tabs.xml I can set the following property on android.support.design.widget.TabLayout:

```
app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/white"
```

However, I want to use a style by setting:

```
   android:theme="@style/TabsLight"
```

then defining:

```
<style name="TabsLight" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="app:tabIndicatorColor">@android:color/white</item>
 </style>
```

This doesn't work, giving me error:

```
Error APT0000: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'app:tabIndicatorColor'. (APT0000)
```

Why am I getting this error (which doesn't happen if I set the property on the layout directly) and how do I resolve it?

The namespace "app" is defined in tabs.xml as:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: Do you have a `res/values/attrs.xml` file that defines the `tabIndicatorColor` attribute? More information in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3441986/49489

Comment: No, why would I need that? This is an attribute defined by AppCompat library, I believe

Comment: Because that makes the `tabIndicatorColor` name available to use in your namespace and corresponding `R.java` file.

Comment: @Barend Check my edit. It works fine on the layout itself

Comment: Hang on, I may have been confused.

Comment: Yeah, forget all I wrote. Sorry.