# how to look throuth android Attribute document

Tags: android, attributes

```
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/designer_cell_background" />
    <solid android:color="@color/designer_cell_background" />
    <corners
        android:radius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"/>
    <padding android:bottom="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

just like this code,if  i want to know what attributes shape has and what's  meaning  they are separetly. How should I do,Is there any document 
to refer to .Thank everyone for help in advance.

Comment: Check this link http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#shape

Comment: thank you very much for your advice , it's very good!

Comment: posted as an answer, please mark it as accepted if it works for you, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes that you can can define for shape are:

- `visible`: Determines if drawable is visible.
- `shape`: rectangle, oval, line, ring
- `innerRadiusRatio`: Only valid if shape == 'ring'. Inner radius of the ring expressed as a ratio of the ring's width. This value is ignored if innerRadius is defined.
- `innerRadius`:   Only valid if shape == 'ring'. Inner radius of the ring. When defined, innerRadiusRatio is ignored. When undefined, innerRadiusRatio's default is used.
- `thicknessRatio`: Only valid if shape == 'ring'. Thickness of the ring expressed as a ratio of the ring's width. This value is ignored if thickness is defined.
- `thickness`: Only valid if shape == 'ring'. Thickness of the ring. When defined, thicknessRatio is ignored. When undefined, thicknessRatio's default is used.
- `useLevel`: Only valid if shape == 'ring'. Allows one to draw only part of the ring (arc-wise), by modifying the drawable's level. This setting only makes sense in context of a  (LevelListDrawable).

---

The children that you can can define for `shape` are:

- `size`:  Determines the size of the shape.
- `gradient`:  Adds a background gradient to the shape.
- `solid`: Adds a solid background color to the shape. Overides gradient element.
- `stroke`: Adds a border to the shape.
- `corners`: Adds rounded corners to the shape.
- `padding`: The padding for the content within this drawable.

---

[Reference](http://idunnolol.com/android/drawables.html#shape)

Answer (score 0):

The first stop you need is the [documentation on Accessing Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html).

There is also another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs) that covers a lot of it, but I won't repeat here, and they also recommend the documentation.

Comment: I have look through your answer,and I still hava a question that  how I can  know what attribute can place in shape element in previous code.

Answer (score 0):

we can search shape attributes by google !

And then it will show this

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape.

Yes, there is almost everything we need about Android in developer.android.com .