# Where is the documentation for Android resource XML's `<attr>` element?

Tags: android, android-resources

I was reading Ha Duy Trung's tutorial [Supporting multiple themes in your Android app](http://www.hidroh.com/2015/02/25/support-multiple-themes-android-app-part-2/) and in it he has the following snippet for `values/attrs.xml`:

```
<attr name="themedMenuStoryDrawable" format="reference" />
<attr name="themedMenuCommentDrawable" format="reference" />
```

Where is this `<attr>` element actually documented? Looking in the Android API Guide [Providing Resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html), I cannot find any mention of this type of element.

I did find a mention of `<attr>` elements in [Creating a View Class](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr), but there they all appear inside of `<declare-styleable>` elements, and there is hardly any explanation of how these elements work.

Is there proper reference documentation for the `<attr>` element? If not, then:

- What does it mean to have an `<attr>` element directly under `<resources>`?
- What is the meaning of the `format` attribute, and what values can it take?
- What other XML attributes can `<attr>` take?
- Can `<attr>` appear as the child of anything other than `<resources>` and `<declare-styleable>`?

I'd specifically like to know how to use `<attr>` in the context of theming (rather than custom views) though documentation of how it works in general would be even better.

Comment: Duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs

Comment: Yeah, I think that answers all four of your bullets (also - suprisingly still minimal documentation, 7 years later...).

Comment: @AdamS While some of the info those answers is useful, that question, and its answers are focused on implementing custom attributes for custom views, which is what the Creating a View Class page I linked to also discusses. That isn't what the tutorial I linked to is doing, and it isn't really clear to me how to get from the use-case described on those pages to the behavior described in the tutorial I linked to.

Comment: Hmm, I see, you're looking to understand how (or perhaps, _why_?) attributes work with theming (vs providing properties to a custom view inside the layout).

Comment: @AdamS yes. I was hoping for reference docs to understand how attr works in general, but my immediate goal is to understand the specific case of theming. I wish the Android documentation team would put at least half the effort into writing complete references that they put into writing overly specific tutorials.

Comment: I'm having trouble putting into words exactly what I'm thinking, and I believe that is because I am confused about what you are confused about. When you say "my immediate goal is to understand the specific case of theming", I don't really know what you mean. Is it that you want to know why `<item name="themedMenuStoryDrawable">` can be declared inside a `<style>` element? Is it that you want to know why `?attr/themedMenuCommentDrawable` can be referenced in a menu resource? Is it something else? I'd love to work through this.

Comment: @BenP. Through experimentation and scouring various tutorials I've been able to infer answers to some of my questions, though even more have been raised. I feel like a blind man groping at an elephant. Why are there no reference docs? For example, I now know that the value of an `<attr>` is determined by the `<item>` with the same name in the `<style>` that is named by the `android:theme` attribute, and that you can refer to an `<attr>` in resource XML using the `?attrName` syntax.

Comment: @BenP. I don't understand is how precedence/cascading work. A `<style>` can have a parent.  In addition to an activity having an `android:theme`, views can also have this attribute, as can their ancestors. Style names are also "dotted", eg: "ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar". Is this just convention or does "foo.bar.baz" fall back to "foo.bar"? So given all of these, how is a particular `<attr>` value found if the current view has no theme, or if the style referred to by the theme does not directly contain that attr?

Comment: @BenP. Also, where can I find a complete list of system themes and support library themes? What attrs do they contain, how do they support overriding, and where an I expected to use each of them? This all seems to be spread across various random tutorials and blog posts rather than in reference docs.