# Attribute:buttonColor not found

Tags: android

I have added a new activity and didn't change anything in any xml files.

This is the exact error:

> Error:error: attribute 'com.littlekidsmath.yoong.quiz:buttonColor'
>   not found.

Here is my **activity_game_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.littlekidsmath.yoong.quiz.MainGameActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/lightGreen"
    android:minHeight="?actionBarSize">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/coinImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/coin" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/coinText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text=""
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/coinImage"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/triviaQuizText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/timeText"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/coinText" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/time"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"></View>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/triviaQuestion"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/question"
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/green"
        android:textSize="30sp" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:onClick="buttonA"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        fbutton:buttonColor="@color/white"
        fbutton:cornerRadius="10dp"
        fbutton:shadowColor="@color/grey" />

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:onClick="buttonB"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        fbutton:buttonColor="@color/white"
        fbutton:cornerRadius="10dp"
        fbutton:shadowColor="@color/grey" />


    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonC"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:onClick="buttonC"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        fbutton:buttonColor="@color/white"
        fbutton:cornerRadius="10dp"
        fbutton:shadowColor="@color/grey" />

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonD"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:onClick="buttonD"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="@color/grey"
        fbutton:buttonColor="@color/white"
        fbutton:cornerRadius="10dp"
        fbutton:shadowColor="@color/grey" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please share your FButton class and attributes

Comment: It seems no attributes named 'buttoncolor' in your attr.xml file. [Check this for Custom Attr](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3441986/4824088)