# Cannot find the setter for attribute in Data binding

Tags: android, data-binding, kotlin, android-livedata

I am using LiveData, DataBinding, and Kotlin in my application.

I defined a Binding Adapter for a RecyclerView like this:

```
   class MainListBindings {

    private val TAG = "TasksListBindings"

    companion object {

        @JvmStatic
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @BindingAdapter("main_items")
        fun setItems(recyclerView: RecyclerView, items: MutableLiveData<List<Homeitem>>? = null) {

            val adapter: RecyclerMainAdapter = recyclerView.adapter as RecyclerMainAdapter
            //prevent use of null list
            items?.let {

                adapter.swapData(items)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

and my reyclerView in XML assigned to this bindingAdapter like this:

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/main_recycler"
      app:main_items="@{viewmodel.items}"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

And in my ViewModel, I used

```
val items = MutableLiveData<List<Homeitem>>()
```

to create the list.

But I am getting this error at building Application:

```
Found data binding errors.
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:main_items' with parameter type android.arch.lifecycle.MutableLiveData<java.util.List<project.data.pojo.Homeitem>> on android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView. file:/home/user/Yara/bazinama_mag/bazinama/app/src/main/res/layout/fragment_main.xml loc:22:24 - 22:38 ****\ data binding error ****
```

Comment: did you declare attribute for the property `main_items` for RecyclerView? in file `Res\values\attrs.xml`

Comment: No, I didn't do that

Comment: have a look at this SO post https://stackoverflow.com/a/3441986/1876355

Comment: @Pierre this is pretty oldschool and not really necessary in this case, since Ehsan can use BindingAdapters

Comment: okay so then the only method missing within `Homeitem` is `public void setMainItems(...);` ?

Comment: Hello Ehsan, did you try removing leading `app:` namespace in at  `@BindingAdapter("app:main_items")`?

Comment: @KasimRangwala Hello, Yes I tried that but didn't work.

Comment: have you found out the solution?, I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @Andrea I Post my solution. Hope that will help you.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There might be different reasons for this error but in my case, the problem raised up because I didn't add `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` And `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` in my `Gradle`.

After adding these plugins you have to replaced your `annotationProcessors` with `kapt`.

After that, every thing might be going well.

Comment: How do you replace the "annotationProcessors" Is that in a file or something?

Comment: in your ```gradle``` file just replace ```annotationProcessors```  with ```kapt```

Comment: I really missed this in the docs. I was looking where my code was wrong while it was just the kotlin-kapt all along

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried everything, was on this for about 2 hours. :D

Answer (score 6):

**Binding Adapter**

```
    @JvmStatic
    @BindingAdapter("main_items")
    fun setItems(recyclerView: RecyclerView, items: MutableLiveData<List<String>>) {

    }
```

**Model**

```
 class User : ViewModel(){
        lateinit var list: MutableLiveData<List<String>>
    }
```

**Bind Data**

```
 val items = ViewModelProviders.of(this@FragmentName)
                .get(RecyclerViewHelper.User::class.java)
    mBinding!!.user = items
```

**Layout**

```
<layout>
     <data>
        <variable
            name="user"
            type="com.XXX.view.recylerview.RecyclerViewHelper.User" />
    </data>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/helper_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            app:main_items="@{user.list}" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: it doesn't work. Also I update my question with this changes

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have any space after the `@BindingAdapter` value like this:

```
@BindingAdapter("sleepDurationFormatted ")
                                       ^
                                       |
                                      here
```

Took me 2hours to find out.

Comment: I fixed mine. It's a typo

Answer (score 0):

2023 here.
Have to refactor a 2021 project.

My problem was that I wasn’t actually specifying exactly the type from the VM.

XML:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/location"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text="@{viewModel.location}”
```

And the VM:

```
    val location = session.location?.toLongString()
```

Fixing this with:

```
    val location: CharSequence = session.location?.toLongString() ?:""
```