# DataBinding - boolean condition not evaluated as it should

Tags: java, android, conditional-statements, android-databinding

In my xml I set visiblity condition for control as follows:

```
android:visibility="@{event.isMessage?(event.dateEventText!=null? View.VISIBLE:View.GONE):View.VISIBLE}"
```

So, if `event.isMessage` is true, this: `(event.dateEventText!=null? View.VISIBLE:View.GONE)` should be evalueated, otherwise, `View.VISIBE` should be returned.

But data binding throws error message:

> ****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:visibility' with parameter type boolean on
>   android.widget.TextView

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: I tried your code and it works with no compiler errors, try cleaning the project, invalidate cash and restart the AS.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.
.
.
android:visibility="@{event.isMessage &amp;&amp; event.dateEventText!=null ?  View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
.
.
.
```

Comment: Syntax error && unescaped, also I don't understand why first approach does not work

Comment: Do you cover your entire xml layout with <layout></layout> tags ? This should work as expected, i will try it myself

Comment: I also dont know why first approach doesnt work, see answer, i updated to &amp;&amp;

Comment: I did, I already have some simplery conditions already, they work.

Comment: Weird, I see no mistake in first approach

Comment: this condition doesn't match the first one. Here if isMessage is false the visibility is GONE and in the question it should be VISIBLE

Answer (score 1):

I checked this approach because it looks okay. and it works. However you can check getter setter of Model, View class import in XML.

Following Code Works Well.

**Event.class**

```
public class Event {
    boolean isMessage;
    String dateEventText;

    public boolean isMessage() {
        return isMessage;
    }

    public void setMessage(boolean message) {
        isMessage = message;
    }

    public String getDateEventText() {
        return dateEventText;
    }

    public void setDateEventText(String dateEventText) {
        this.dateEventText = dateEventText;
    }
}
```

**layout_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="event"
            type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.data.Event" />

    </data>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="@{event.isMessage?(event.dateEventText!=null? View.VISIBLE:View.GONE):View.VISIBLE}" />

</layout>
```

### Suggestion:

Move your logical part in Handler.

**1. Create Handler**

*EventHandler.class*

```
public class EventHandler {
    private Event event;

    public EventHandler(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public int getTextVisibility() {
        if (event.isMessage && event.dateEventText != null) return View.VISIBLE;
        else return View.GONE;
    }
}
```

**2. Import Handler in Layout**

```
    <variable
        name="handler"
        type="com.innovanathinklabs.sample.data.EventHandler" />
```

**3. Set handler value from activity**

```
activity.setHandler(new EventHandler(yourEventModel))
```

**4. Use handler method to set visibility**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="@{handler.textVisibility}" />
```

**That's all!**

#### Another Approach

If you don't want add new class of Handler. You can also place visibility method in model class.

**1. Put getTextVisibility method in Model**

```
public class Event{
    // other variables
    public int getTextVisibility() {
        if (event.isMessage && event.dateEventText != null) return View.VISIBLE;
        else return View.GONE;
    }
}
```

**2. Use in layout**

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="@{event.textVisibility}" />
```

Comment: Also check if kotlin plugin is applied. Check this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53039966/6891563

Answer (score 0):

You can have boolean to int conversion adapter. If it's static (the same way as `BindingAdapter`), it will convert boolean fields which expect integer (e.g. `View.VISIBLE`).

```java
@BindingConversion
int convertBooleanToVisibility(boolean isVisible) {
    return isVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE;
}
```

In XML you'd use your method which return boolean for visibiliy:

```xml
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="@{event.isMessageVisible()}" />
```

Comment: Why should I use it instead of getter returning `int`? I guess benfit is that it will convert all occurences automatically? Just like converters in wpf binding

Comment: yes, exactly .. the benefit is, that you can use everywhere just boolean flag to show/hide (visible/gone) view