# Android Studio 3.4 Kotlin BindingAdapter crashes the ap

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I have been trying to use BindingAdapter in Android Studio 3.4 (the last update) with Kotlin for days now and nothing seems to work.

I first tried with the following tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-databinding/#7
And it was outputing an error as soon as I reached the 8th step.

Furthermore I tried the simple example possible with an Empty Application, a single Activity, a single ViewModel, and a single BindingAdapter. Here is the XML code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable name="viewmodel" 
                  type="com.example.testbindingadapter.DataViewModel"/>
    </data>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:greetings="@{viewmodel.name}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
                android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Now here is the ViewModel with the BindingAdapter

```
class DataViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val _name = MutableLiveData<String>()
    val name : LiveData<String> = _name
    init {
        _name.value = "Amath"
    }
}

@BindingAdapter("greetings")
fun setName(view: TextView, text: String) {
    view.text = "Welcome, $text"
}
```

I have also enabled dataBinging in my Graddle. I added `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` as suggested in the following thread [Cannot find the setter for attribute in Data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926663/cannot-find-the-setter-for-attribute-in-data-binding). At first I had an error `msg:Cannot find the setter for attribute databinding` subsequently the error disappeared, but the app simply crashed.

Can you help ?

Comment: Did you set binding.viewmodel = viewModel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never set the viewmodel into databinding:

`binding.viewmodel = viewModel`