# How to group custom attributes in Android Studio layout designer?

Tags: android-studio, attributes

The title says everything, what I'm trying to achieve is to group custom attrs in the layout designer, just like layout_margin or padding, but with diferent type of attributes if it is possible

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6krM.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "group custom attributes"? Can you please describe more and give some examples?

Comment: Yes, of course, I have added an image to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't fully understand your question. From the image, I guess you want to make a single line of combo attribute which can cover all the attributes under it. This grouping is not possible I guess. But if u want to make some custom attributes, u can use this:
[Defining custom attrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs)

Answer (score 0):

What I found in my research that, you cannot make groups for your custom attributes. If you look at the [attrs.xml](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/attrs.xml#L2439) file, you will see there are no extra things/conditions about grouping `padding` and its related attributes, but Android Studio shows the attributes as a group. So I think Android Studio developers create custom conditions for those attributes to group up those attributes.

Comment: Yes, that was my initial thought, that grouping is hard coded into the IDE. Well, thanks you anyway!