# How to use TypedArray.getResourceId() method returned value?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-custom-view, typed-arrays

I'm learning about *Custom View*, and i created a  Styleable node for, one of the attribute is from a reference type, that is set in the xml file to a **style**. I don't know how to retrieve attributes values from the this style.
Styleable:

Styleable:

```
    <resources>
        <declare-styleable name="MultiButton">
            <attr name="numOfButtons" format="integer" />
            <attr name="activeButtonIndex" format="integer" />
            <attr name="backgroundSelector" format="reference"/>
            <attr name="buttons_style" format="reference"/>
        </declare-styleable>
   </resources>
```

Style:

```
<style name="MultiButtonStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_purple</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
</style>
```

xml:

```
    <com.example.currencyconvertor.MultiButton
    android:id="@+id/multiButton"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:activeButtonIndex="0"
    app:backgroundSelector="@drawable/multi_button_background_selector"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:numOfButtons="2"
    buttons_style="@style/MultiButtonStyle />
```

Code:

```
public MultiButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs )
{
    TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.MultiButton);
    int resId = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.MultiButton_buttons_style, -1));
}
```

I want to get all attributes that are defined under the style i have set for **buttons_style** attributes.
Now, i don't understand/know what to write in after setting the *resId* variable in order to get it.

Answer that was suggested a duplicate question doesn't refer to reference type, so *getResoueceId* method isn't explain there

Comment: Please, refer to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs] or [https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Defining custom attrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441396/defining-custom-attrs)

Comment: @AugustoCarmo, first link doesn't supply an example for how to get a resource type from TypedArray, second link is broken.

Comment: Sorry. Try now: https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view

Comment: @AugustoCarmo, thanks but link doesn't explain how to use the method that is in title. I have difficult only with *getResourceId* method

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the following code and see if it helps you:

```
TypedArray typedArray = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.MultiButton);
int resId = typedArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.MultiButton_buttons_style, THE_DEDAULT_RES_ID));
```

typedArray.**getResourceId**(...)

Comment: thanks. But you wrote exactly the code that i have wrote in the question (you only change the default value in the second line). I don't  know how to continue from this point

Comment: Your post: `typedArray.getInt(...)`, My answer: `typedArray.getResourceId(...)`  :)

Comment: You are right. it was a mistake in writing the code. But i mean to *getResourceId*, so question still relevant :(.