# Android: Jetpack Compose and XML in Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-custom-view, compose-multiplatform

How can I add Jetpack Compose & xml in the same activity? An example would be perfect.

Answer (score 122):

If you want to use a Compose in your XML file, you can add this to your layout file:

```xml
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
  android:id="@+id/my_composable"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and then, set the content:

```kotlin
findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.my_composable).setContent {
  MaterialTheme {
    Surface {
      Text(text = "Hello!")
    }
  }
}
```

If you want the opposite, i.e. to use an XML file in your compose, you can use this:

```kotlin
AndroidView(
  factory = { context ->
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null, false)
    val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)

    // do whatever you want...
    view // return the view
  },
  update = { view ->
    // Update the view
  }
)
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation it's really saving time.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta muy amable y acertada

Comment: See also https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/compose-in-views.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to provide your composable like a regular *View* (with the ability to specify its attributes in XML), subclass from *AbstractComposeView*.

```kotlin
@Composable 
fun MyComposable(title: String) {
    Text(title)
}
```

```kotlin
// Do not forget these two imports for the delegation (by) to work
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

class MyCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : AbstractComposeView(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    var myProperty by mutableStateOf("A string")

    init {
        // See the footnote
        context.withStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyStyleable) {
            myProperty = getString(R.styleable.MyStyleable_myAttribute)
        }
    }

    // The important part
    @Composable override fun Content() {
        MyComposable(title = myProperty)
    }
}
```

And this is how you would use it just like a regular View:

```xml
<my.package.name.MyCustomView
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:myAttribute="Helloooooooooo!" />
```

Thanks to ProAndroidDev for [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/jetpack-compose-interop-part-2-using-compose-in-traditional-android-views-and-layouts-with-a3c50fc2eaa5).

#### Footnote

To define your own custom attributes for your view, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3441396/8583692).
Also, make sure to use **-ktx** version of the [AndroidX Core](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core) library to be able to access useful Kotlin extension functions like `Context::withStyledAttributes`:

```kotlin
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0")
```

Comment: Nothing to add except to remark that this is a wonderful answer, each step cleared a new question I thought of and with bonus info to make life easier. Hands down this is the best way to integrate small new Compose views into legacy XML apps.

Comment: How to change parameters in runtime and update a view?

Comment: Throws error "java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.Content(androidx.compose.runtime.Composer, int)".

Comment: For example, changing `myProperty`?

Answer (score 12):

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop?hl=en

> To embed an XML layout, use the [AndroidViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/viewinterop/package-summary?hl=en#AndroidViewBinding(kotlin.Function3,%20androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,%20kotlin.Function1)) API, which is provided by the `androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding` library. To do this, your project must enable view binding.
> AndroidView, like many other built-in composables, takes a Modifier parameter that can be used, for example, to set its position in the parent composable.

```
@Composable
fun AndroidViewBindingExample() {
    AndroidViewBinding(ExampleLayoutBinding::inflate) {
        exampleView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Updated : When you want to use XML file in compose function

```kotlin
AndroidView(
  factory = { context ->
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.test_layout, null, false)
    val edittext= view.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext)

    view 
  },
  update = {  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xml element <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView />
and by adding this in your layout file you can either use it with data binding or by findviewbyId to use it in your activity/fragment and define your compose UI in setContent method. For further detailed example you can look this article
https://medium.com/p/51662a94c552