# is it possible to add XML on top of ComposeView?

Tags: android, xml, android-jetpack-compose

I know it's possible to add ComposeView inside XML view, but is it possible to add XML on top of ComposeView.
The problem is I have pre-existing fragments on the main layout but, now I want to make my main layout screen with compose without changing the XML fragment screens is it possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Jetpack Compose and XML in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65648904/android-jetpack-compose-and-xml-in-activity)

Comment: no, this one says I can add compose view inside XML, which I know. but I want the opposite. I want to display the XML view inside compose view.

Comment: You haven't read the second part of the answer which contains "If you want the opposite, i.e. to use an XML file in your compose, you can use this:"