# Is it possible to use both Android jetpack Compose views and xml files together in same Activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, fragmentmanager

I am facing an issue in my Android app where I'm unable to use **supportFragmentManager** in my **ComponentActivity** subclass. As per my understanding, ComponentActivity does not support the FragmentManager out of the box. And if I want to use **supportFragmentManager** Activity should be subclasses of AppCompatActivity or FragmentActivity. However, I'm encountering a problem where it seems to be unavailable. **I want to use both JetPack Compose and XML in my class**,

I have followed this https://stackoverflow.com/a/65653754/3467187

```
class AbcActivity : ComponentActivity(n) {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_permissio)
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
         // Here I want to use supposrtFragmentManger
    }
}
```

}

Gradle file look like this,

```
dependencies {

implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.0")
..
}
```

Any idea to use both JetPack Compose and XML in same class in a way I could use fragment Manager?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Compose in your XMLs and also the other way around.

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65653754/14120486) answer.

### Method 1

#### 1. Add `ComposeView` to you XML

```
<androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
android:id="@+id/my_composable"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

#### 2. Set the content from you activity

```
findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.my_composable).setContent {
    MaterialTheme {
        Surface {
          Text(text = "Hello!")
        }
    }
}
```

### Method 2

You can use `AndroidViewBinding`.

Before jumping on with this method, read [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/viewinterop/package-summary?hl=en#AndroidViewBinding(kotlin.Function3,%20androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,%20kotlin.Function1))

```
@Composable
fun AndroidViewBindingExample() {
    AndroidViewBinding(ExampleLayoutBinding::inflate) {
        exampleView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
    }
}
```

### XML in Compose

```
AndroidView(
    factory = { context ->
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null, false)
        val textView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.text)

        // do whatever you want...
        view // return the view
      },
    update = { view ->
    // Update the view
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and easy. I have found it as a requirement and implemented it myself. You can go through the article to understand.
https://medium.com/p/51662a94c552