# How to migrate my custom view to Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-custom-view, android-jetpack, compose-multiplatform

I have a [custom view](https://github.com/mahozad/android-pie-chart) created the traditional way: subclassing from the *View* class.

Specifically, my custom view has many custom attributes (and their corresponding Kotlin properties) that can be assigned in the XML layout:

```xml
<com.example.MyCustomView
    app:myCustomAttr1 = "..."
    app:myCustomAttr2 = "..."/>
```

##### How to provide a *View* version of my composable so users can use it in XML?

Besides using *[AndroidView](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#views-in-compose)* class to load a conventional Android view in Jetpack Compose, how can I **convert** my view to be a "true" Compose component?

Should I provide a separate composable for every part of my custom view?
For example, a composable for the pie, another composable for the legend box?

[Android developer documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop) does not mention how to transform custom views to Compose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I have created a composable version of my view like this:

```kotlin
@Composable fun MyComposable(title: String) {
    Text(title)
}
```

to use that composable like a regular *View* (with the ability to specify its attributes in XML), we should create a custom view subclassing from *AbstractComposeView*:

```kotlin
// Do not forget these two imports for the delegation (by) to work
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

class MyCustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyle: Int = 0
) : AbstractComposeView(context, attrs, defStyle) {

    var myProperty by mutableStateOf("A string")

    init {
        // See the footnote
        context.withStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MyStyleable) {
            myProperty = getString(R.styleable.MyStyleable_myAttribute)
        }
    }

    // The important part
    @Composable override fun Content() {
        MyComposable(title = myProperty)
    }
}
```

And this is how we would use it just like a regular view in XML:

```xml
<my.package.name.MyCustomView
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:myAttribute="Helloooooooooo!" />
```

and/or in an activity:

```kotlin
val myCustomView = findViewById<MyCustomView>(R.id.myView)
myCustomView.myProperty = "Woohoo!"
```

Thanks to ProAndroidDev for [this article](https://proandroiddev.com/jetpack-compose-interop-part-2-using-compose-in-traditional-android-views-and-layouts-with-a3c50fc2eaa5).

#### Footnote

To define your own custom attributes for your view, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3441396/8583692).
Also, make sure to use **-ktx** version of the [AndroidX Core](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/core) library to be able to access useful Kotlin extension functions like `Context::withStyledAttributes`:

```kotlin
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0")
```