# Custom view custom attribute not being set without @{}

Tags: android, kotlin, view, attributes

So I've got a custom view with this attribute:

```kotlin
    private var mLabelText: String = "DEFAULT"
    var labelText: String
        set(value) {
            if (mLabelText != value) {
                mLabelText = value
                invalidate()
            }
        }
        get() { return mLabelText }
```

And defined in `attr.xml` as

```xml
    <declare-styleable name="CustomView">
        <attr name="labelText" format="string"/>
    </declare-styleable>
```

Now if I try to do this in my layout XML to set the value, it doesnt work (the text still shows 'DEFAULT')

```xml
        <CustomView
            ...
            app:text="NewText" />
```

However, if I do this, it works:

```xml
        <CustomView
            ...
            app:text="@{`NewText`}" />
```

So what gives?
How come views like `TextView` allow me to do `android:text="Text"` instead of having to write `` android:text="@{`Text`} ``, but my own custom view wont?

Comment: The second one is being handled by the data binding framework, which is generating code to set that for you when it detects the `@{}` value in processing that layout. The first setup is just a plain old attribute value, though, and the binding framework won't do anything with it, so unless you've handled that attribute in your custom `View`'s constructor, that property is not going to be set automatically.

Comment: I noticed that you referred to `var labelText` as an attribute, which might be where part of the confusion lies. That is not an attribute; that's just a regular Kotlin property. The attribute is defined only by the `<attr>` element, and is basically just the `app:labelText` entry in the XML. To wire that attribute up to your `var labelText` property, you'd have to read its value from the `AttributeSet` passed into the `View`'s constructor, like is shown in the last block in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3441986) (it's in Java, but the Kotlin is basically the same).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike's comments answer the confusion I had about the different syntaxes.

What I ended up doing ultimately is to inherit the existing android TextView. TextView has a bunch of stuff I needed like font, font size etc, so it was just simpler to inherit rather than re-implement it myself.