# http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android where does this URL point...?

Tags: android, android-layout, xml-namespaces

I am not getting where is url: **http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android** ?
Can somebody please let me know where does this point to?
Why cannot we access this URL mentioned in `xmlns:android` namespace for android xml ?

Comment: it's an XML schema, it defines how your XML should be structured, it can also be used for XML validation and it's not a URL

Answer (score 3):

You can't access it as it's a `URI` not a `URL`, the difference is well explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp) :

> Uniform Resource Identifier (URI)
>
> A Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) is a string of characters which identifies an Internet Resource.
>
> The most common URI is the Uniform Resource Locator (URL) which identifies an Internet domain address. Another, not so common type of URI is the Universal Resource Name (URN).

So, in some cases you might be able to access it and it'll probably have the description of the namespace.

Comment: Why is a protocol (http) the schema? I do understand that https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986 has a brief comment on that in 1.2.2, but I do not quite understand why it's done this way.

Comment: @kaiya you can read about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5758068/6518605

Answer (score 0):

It specifies XML namespace.
So we have to understand what a XML namespace is:
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp

And why we use URI in name space:
[Why are URLs in XML namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758041/why-are-urls-in-xml-namespaces)