# WPF strange name of namespaces

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

I noticed that standard namespaces in WPF have strange names such as

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
```

Well, I can understand naming convention like CompanyName.Technology.Product etc, but I can't get why Microsoft coders use URL ardress. Does it have any practical sence or it's just for fun?

Comment: First, XAML is XML. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5758041/4924596)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called as **URI** (Uniform Resource Identifier). It is a  recommended standard defined by W3C for XML namespaces.

For more details, check out this [XML Namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace#Namespace_declaration) page from wiki.