# Why can't we use random strings instead of URI's for XML namespaces?

Tags: xml, xsd, uri, xml-namespaces, xml-validation

I'm trying to understand the reasons of the XML-namespaces convention (using URI for namespaces).

I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5758041/why-are-urls-in-xml-namespaces) on StackOverflow. I understand that namespace's fullname should be unique. But I still don't understand why can't we just use random strings for this?

For example, we're trying to distinguish the real cars from the toy cars in our file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<carstore xmlns:real="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws/cars/real" xmlns:toy="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws/cars/toy">
<real:car category="truck">
    <model lang="en">Scania R 770</model>
    <year>2005</year>
    <price currency="US dollar">200000.00</price>
</real:car>
<toy:car category="sedan">
    <title lang="en">Ford Focus</title>
    <year>2012</year>
    <price currency="US dollar">100.00</price>
</toy:car>
</carstore>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<carstore xmlns:real="heroigairehgoiaer7272" xmlns:toy="289ry89fhfhbvnsdkljnv">
<real:car category="truck">
<model lang="en">Scania R 770</model>
<year>2005</year>
<price currency="US dollar">200000.00</price>
</real:car>
<toy:car category="sedan">
<title lang="en">Ford Focus</title>
<year>2012</year>
<price currency="US dollar">100.00</price>
</toy:car>
</carstore>
```

I'll be grateful if someone will explain why this option

```
xmlns:real="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws/cars/real"
```

is better than this one:

```
xmlns:real="heroigairehgoiaer7272"
```

What negative consequences can we face using the second one?
Probably there is any real-life examples?

Comment: In case you’re not aware of it: You can use a URI that consists of a random string, namely a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), e.g. `urn:uuid:6e8bc430-9c3a-11d9-9669-0800200c9a66`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Random, *unique*, strings *could* be used for namespace values, however...

### URI-based namespaces offer advantages over random strings:

1. **Leveraging
    the in-place ownership mechanisms** of domain names avoids having to 
    replicate that functionality for control of namespaces.
2. Domain names **communicate ownership**, which is useful for identifying a
    party or project responsible for a namespace.
3. Although [namespace URIs do not have to be retrievable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27613891/290085), they can be and
    often are, thus serving as a **convenient means of retrieval** of governing schemas
    or documentation.
4. **Hierarchical nature** of URI's can mirror the natural hierarchical
    organization of name collections.