# What happens if the namespace's website is no longer accessible?

Tags: c#, xaml

For example, if in a year I decide to use the namespace 'xmlns:x ...' in my application, what would happen if the site "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" no longer exists?

```
<Window xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

Comment: That's **NOT** a website, or a link, or a URL. It's just a string with no further meaning or interpretation, just generally following a convention of resembling a link. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5758041/2557263) for further details. In fact, if we pretend that that schema is a URL and go to it, right now we get a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely nothing; it is a URI, not a URL; it does not need to exist in any sense. To quote from RFC 3986 §1.2.2:

> The URI itself only provides identification; access to the resource is neither guaranteed nor implied by the presence of a URI.

It is just a recognizable string, nothing else. If it resolves to something, that's nice but not required in any way.