# Custom XML tags won't settle?

Tags: android, xml, tags, custom-attributes, typed-arrays

I am truly stumped. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695646/declaring-a-custom-android-ui-element-using-xml/2695649) link in learning how to create custom xml tags for my views. Well as far as I can tell I did everything correctly. But eclipse still tosses `error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'radius' in package 'com.theliraeffect.fantasy'`

Can you guys take a look?

hexmap.xml

```
<com.theliraeffect.fantasy.HexMap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:hexmap="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.theliraeffect.fantasy"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  hexmap:radius="3"/>
```

attrs.xml

```
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="HexMap">
        <attr name="radius"/>
    </declare-styleable>

</resources>
```

Just in case (although I doubt it has anything to do with it).

```
package com.theliraeffect.fantasy;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class HexMap extends View {

    HexMap(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defstyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defstyle);
        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.hexmap);

        a.recycle();
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side note: Other than the starting activity (which I haven't touched) this is the entire project. I started an entirely new project just to work with this.

Comment: From the link you provided `Non-standard android attributes need to have their type declared` , which , I'm guessing means you have to add `format=".."` for `radius` in attrs.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Harism - Thanks, that was it. I thought that integer was a default setting and didn't need specification. It works now. If you change your comment to an answer, I will give you the credit.